# How to put filenames into an array from os.listdir

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Lets say you input: `os.listdir(r'filepath')`

and the output is: `['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt','d.txt','e.txt']`

How could you put the file names, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
L =  ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt','d.txt','e.txt']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[x.split('.')[0] for x in L]})
print (df)
  col
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

Thank you for suggestion @Joe Halliwell, main advantage is general solution, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542596):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in L]})
```

Comment: I'd suggest it's very slightly better to us `os.path.splitext`