# Should I use `import os.path` or `import os`?

Tags: python, coding-style, python-import

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), `os.path` is a module. Thus, what is the preferred way of importing it?

```
# Should I always import it explicitly?
import os.path
```

Or...

```
# Is importing os enough?
import os
```

Please DON'T answer "importing `os` works for me". I know, it works for me too right now (as of Python 2.6). What I want to know is any official recommendation about this issue. So, if you answer this question, please **post your references**.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`os.path` works in a funny way. It looks like `os` should be a package with a submodule `path`, but in reality `os` is a normal module that does magic with `sys.modules` to inject `os.path`. Here's what happens:

- When Python starts up, it loads a bunch of modules into `sys.modules`. They aren't bound to any names in your script, but you can access the already-created modules when you import them in some way.

  - `sys.modules` is a dict in which modules are cached. When you import a module, if it already has been imported somewhere, it gets the instance stored in `sys.modules`.
- `os` is among the modules that are loaded when Python starts up. It assigns its `path` attribute to an os-specific path module.
- It injects `sys.modules['os.path'] = path` so that you're able to do "`import os.path`" as though it was a submodule.

I tend to think of `os.path` as *a module I want to use* rather than *a thing in the `os` module*, so even though it's not *really* a submodule of a package called `os`, I import it sort of like it is one and **I always do `import os.path`**. This is consistent with how `os.path` is documented.

---

Incidentally, this sort of structure leads to a lot of Python programmers' early confusion about modules and packages and code organization, I think. This is really for two reasons

1. If you think of `os` as a package and know that you can do `import os` and have access to the submodule `os.path`, you may be surprised later when you can't do `import twisted` and automatically access `twisted.spread` without importing it.
2. It is confusing that `os.name` is a normal thing, a string, and `os.path` is a module. I always structure my packages with empty `__init__.py` files so that at the same level I always have one type of thing: a module/package or other stuff. Several big Python projects take this approach, which tends to make more structured code.

Comment: Excellent, very informative answer! Congratulations! Even though it doesn't directly answer the question, it has lots of useful details. But could you please elaborate on "This is consistent with how os.path is documented"? Like Chris Hulan said, the os.walk() example imports just os instead of os.path.

Comment: @Denilson, It does include a direct answer: I always do `import os.path` myself and think that's a nicer way. By "This is consistent with how os.path is documented" I meant that it is given its own page in the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html .

Comment: Wow, `os.py` does indeed inject into `sys.modules['os.path']`. So this is why `from os.path import something` actually works. I was curious about when this was introduced and checked the source. Fun fact: This is from 1999, first included in Python 1.5.2. Original commit is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0237909e420db2897034a371087963be4a312552).

Answer (score 31):

As per [PEP-20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) by Tim Peters, "Explicit is better than implicit" and "Readability counts".  If all you need from the `os` module is under `os.path`, `import os.path` would be more explicit and let others know what you really care about.

Likewise, PEP-20 also says "Simple is better than complex", so if you also need stuff that resides under the more-general `os` umbrella, `import os` would be preferred.

Comment: I don't see how `import os` is really about being "simple" in any meaningful way. Simple != short.

Comment: I was more trying to point out that `import os` **and** a `import os.path` is daft if you e.g. need `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.isfile()`

Comment: Though importing both is unnecessary, I think "daft" is a bit strong.

Answer (score 17):

Definitive answer: `import os` and use `os.path`. do not `import os.path` directly.

From the documentation of the module itself:

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path)
...
Instead of importing this module directly, import os and refer to
this module as os.path.  The "os.path" name is an alias for this
module on Posix systems; on other systems (e.g. Mac, Windows),
os.path provides the same operations in a manner specific to that
platform, and is an alias to another module (e.g. macpath, ntpath).
...
```

Comment: Note that it's not docs for an `os.path` module which doesn't exist, but for `posixpath`.

Comment: That is not at all how I think that docstring is meant to be interpreted, although it is pretty misleading.  Keep in mind that the sentence `"Instead of importing this module directly, import os and refer to
this module as os.path."` is located in `posixpath.py` (or `macpath.py`,  `ntpath.py` etc.).

I'm fairly sure that what they mean is that one should not `import posixpath` (which works), but rather import the module via `os` for better portability. I don't think they intend to give a recommendation as to whether `import os` or `import os.path` is preferred.

Comment: I agree with most of @flornquake 's comment but disagree with the last sentence. Both posixpath.py and ntpath.py say "import os and refer to this module as os.path". They do not say "import os.path and refer to this module as os.path". macpath.py has nothing on the matter.

Comment: This is a good example of showing how a document containing a *this* pointer can be misleading :D

Comment: I can't think of any reason to inject `os.path` into `sys.modules` *except* to allow `import os.path` as an import. If you weren't supposed to use the direct import, why bother adding `os.path` to `sys.modules` in the first place?

Answer (score 11):

Interestingly enough, importing os.path will import all of os.  try the following in the interactive prompt:

```
import os.path
dir(os)
```

The result will be the same as if you just imported os.  This is because os.path will refer to a different module based on which operating system you have, so python will import os to determine which module to load for path.

[reference](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg188236.html)

With some modules, saying `import foo` will not expose `foo.bar`, so I guess it really depends the design of the specific module.

---

In general, just importing the explicit modules you need should be marginally faster.  On my machine:

`import os.path`**:** `7.54285810068e-06` seconds

`import os`**:** `9.21904878972e-06` seconds

These times are close enough to be fairly negligible. Your program may need to use other modules from `os` either now or at a later time, so usually it makes sense just to sacrifice the two microseconds and use `import os` to avoid this error at a later time.  I usually side with just importing os as a whole, but can see why some would prefer `import os.path` to technically be more efficient and convey to readers of the code that that is the only part of the `os` module that will need to be used.  It essentially boils down to a style question in my mind.

Comment: `from os import path` will make the calls to path even faster if speed is the issue.

Comment: Being pythonic, explicit is better than implicit right?
In reality I think it really is the judgment call by the user, whether the user is only going to use os.path or multiple modules within os. Maybe one method is more in line with your philosophy over the other?

Comment: Timing this is some of the prematurest premature optimization I've ever seen. This has never been *anyone's* bottleneck and the time here is immaterial to how someone should code.

Comment: This isn't unique to `os.path`. [As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), any non-top-level module import binds the name of the top-level package in the current name space as well. Importing a module also requires the (implicit) import of the package(s) containing it.

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't find any definitive reference, but I see that the example code for [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) uses os.path but only imports os

Comment: Not (or no longer) true; there's one example that uses `os.path` as a module attribute of `os`, but also an example that uses `from os.path import join, getsize`.  Granted, that has as much to do with the `from ... import ...` statement disallowing something like `from os import path.join as join, path.getsize as getsize`.

Answer (score 6):

Common sense works here: `os` is a module, and `os.path` is a module, too. So just import the module you want to use:

- If you want to use functionalities in the `os` module, then import `os`.
- If you want to use functionalities in the `os.path` module, then import `os.path`.
- If you want to use functionalities in both modules, then import both modules:

  ```
  import os
  import os.path
  ```

For reference:

- [Lib/idlelib/rpc.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/idlelib/rpc.py) uses `os` and imports `os`.
- [Lib/idlelib/idle.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/idlelib/idle.py) uses `os.path` and imports `os.path`.
- [Lib/ensurepip/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py) uses both and imports both.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `os.path` is an *alias* for an OS-specific module with its own name. `import os.path` is redundant if you already have `import os`, since `os` also has an attribute `path` that refers to the same module. (Which is not to say it doesn't have documentation benefits, only that it's not necessary.)

Comment: @chepner The description you gave is useful. But [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) simply mentions `os.path` as a *module* while talking nothing about *alias*. The technical detail is injecting a name into `sys.modules`.

Comment: There is no single module named `os.path`. It's always an alias for either `posixpath` or `ntpath`.

Comment: The same documentation also only links to the files for those two modules. CPython, at least, does not provide a separate or distinct module named `os.path`.