# Importing module from string variable using "__import__" gives different results than a normal import statement

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on a documentation (personal) for nested matplotlib (MPL) library, which differs from MPL own provided, by interested submodule packages. I'm writing Python script which I hope will automate document generation from future MPL releases.

I selected interested submodules/packages and want to list their main classes from which I'll generate list and process it with `pydoc`.

The problem is that I can't find a way to instruct Python to load a submodule from a string. Here is an example of what I tried:

```
import matplotlib.text as text
x = dir(text)
```

```
i = __import__('matplotlib.text')
y = dir(i)
```

```
j = __import__('matplotlib')
z = dir(j)
```

And here is a 3-way comparison of above lists through pprint:

[image]

I don't understand what's loaded in `y` object - it's base `matplotlib` plus something else, but it lacks information that I wanted and that is main classes from `matplotlib.text` package. It's the top blue coloured part on screenshot (`x` list).

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use `__import__(str)` rather than the standard `import` statemetn?

Comment: It's because I'll process lists which items are MPL submodules and get their methods paths

Comment: @thesamet - c'mon - there are endless ideas where you'd want this functionality. When you have a textual configuration of libraries, you can load them by name, which wouldn't quite work with the `import` statement. Here's one example of use: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3048/

Answer (score 354, accepted):

The `__import__` function can be a bit hard to understand.

If you change

```
i = __import__('matplotlib.text')
```

to

```
i = __import__('matplotlib.text', fromlist=[''])
```

then `i` will refer to `matplotlib.text`.

In Python 3.1 or later, you can use `importlib`:

```
import importlib

i = importlib.import_module("matplotlib.text")
```

Some notes

- If you're trying to import something from a sub-folder e.g. `./feature/email.py`, the code will look like `importlib.import_module("feature.email")`
- Before Python 3.3 you could not import anything if there was no `__init__.py` in the folder with file you were trying to import (see [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/9962007) before deciding if you want to keep the file for backward compatibility e.g. with `pytest`).

Comment: `importlib` should be avaliable on pypi for < python2.7

Comment: For anyone who's coming here from Google. It should be noted that if you're trying to import something from a sub-folder (for example, `./feature/email.py`) the code will look like `importlib.import_module("feature.email")`

Comment: Finally, also remember that you can't import anything if there is no `__init__.py` in the folder with file you are trying to import.

Comment: @mzjn This is for `import moduleName` where moduleName is string. How about `from moduleName import *` ?

Comment: @NamGVU: What is the problem? The question title is "import module from string variable". Hasn't that been answered?

Comment: You have perfectly answered the OP. I just expand the topic. Thank you any way!

Comment: Just found answer for my question here in case any one needs it https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306598/248616

Comment: and what if I want to import something like `../../feature/email.py` ?

Comment: I found the answer on how to import from parent directory [here](https://forum.glyphsapp.com/t/python-how-to-import-a-module-from-a-parent-path-for-ga/2210/5).

Comment: Due to implicit namespace packages, it is possible to import from folders without an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 115):

[`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is what you are looking for. It returns the imported module.

```
import importlib

# equiv. of your `import matplotlib.text as text`
text = importlib.import_module('matplotlib.text')
```

You can thereafter access anything in the module as `text.myclass`, `text.myfunction`, etc.

Comment: An alternative is [`imp.load_source(..)` using the `imp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) as suggested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: @gecco This is for `import moduleName` where moduleName is string. How about `from moduleName import *` ?

Comment: Anyone figure out @NamGVU question?

Answer (score 6):

spent some time trying to import modules from a list, and this is the thread that got me most of the way there - but I didnt grasp the use of ___import____ -

so here's how to import a module from a string, and get the same behavior as just import.  And try/except the error case, too. :)

```
  pipmodules = ['pycurl', 'ansible', 'bad_module_no_beer']
  for module in pipmodules:
      try:
          # because we want to import using a variable, do it this way
          module_obj = __import__(module)
          # create a global object containging our module
          globals()[module] = module_obj
      except ImportError:
          sys.stderr.write("ERROR: missing python module: " + module + "\n")
          sys.exit(1)
```

and yes, for python 2.7> you have other options - but for 2.6<, this works.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from using the `importlib` one can also use `exec` method to import a module from a string variable.

Here I am showing an example of importing the `combinations` method from `itertools` package using the `exec` method:

```
MODULES = [
    ['itertools','combinations'],
]

for ITEM in MODULES:
    import_str = "from {0} import {1}".format(ITEM[0],', '.join(str(i) for i in ITEM[1:]))
    exec(import_str)

ar = list(combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
for elements in ar:
    print(elements)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) built-in function that execute any string as a Python code.

```
In [1]: module = 'pandas'
   ...: function = 'DataFrame'
   ...: alias = 'DF'

In [2]: exec(f"from {module} import {function} as {alias}")

In [3]: DF
Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

For me this was the most readable way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Module auto-install & import from list

Below script works fine with both submodules and [pseudo submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725195/2192488).

```py
# PyPI imports
import pkg_resources, subprocess, sys

modules   = {'lxml.etree', 'pandas', 'screeninfo'}
required  = {m.split('.')[0] for m in modules}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing   = required - installed

if missing:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing])

for module in set.union(required, modules):
    globals()[module] = __import__(module)
```

Tests:

```py
print(pandas.__version__)
print(lxml.etree.LXML_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed these 3 useful functions:

```py
def loadModule(moduleName):
    module = None
    try:
        import sys
        del sys.modules[moduleName]
    except BaseException as err:
        pass
    try:
        import importlib
        module = importlib.import_module(moduleName)
    except BaseException as err:
        serr = str(err)
        print("Error to load the module '" + moduleName + "': " + serr)
    return module

def reloadModule(moduleName):
    module = loadModule(moduleName)
    moduleName, modulePath = str(module).replace("' from '", "||").replace("<module '", '').replace("'>", '').split("||")
    if (modulePath.endswith(".pyc")):
        import os
        os.remove(modulePath)
        module = loadModule(moduleName)
    return module

def getInstance(moduleName, param1, param2, param3):
    module = reloadModule(moduleName)
    instance = eval("module." + moduleName + "(param1, param2, param3)")
    return instance
```

And everytime I want to reload a new instance I just have to call getInstance() like this:

```py
myInstance = getInstance("MyModule", myParam1, myParam2, myParam3)
```

Finally I can call all the functions inside the new Instance:

```py
myInstance.aFunction()
```

The only specificity here is to customize the params list (param1, param2, param3) of your instance.