# Import file using string as name

Tags: python, string, import, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

I intend to make a suite of files at some point soon, and the best way to organize it is to have a list, that list will be at the very top of a file, and after it will come a ridiculous amount of code to handle what that list controls and how it operates. I'm looking to write said list only once, and said list is a list of folder and file names in this format:

```
[(folder/filename, bool, bool, int), (folder/filename, bool, bool, int)]
```

As you can see, `folder/filename` are the same (sort of). File name is folder name with `.py` on the end, but doing import XXX you don't need to do import XXX.py, so I don't see this causing an issue.

The problem I'm facing is importing using this method...

```
for (testName, auto, hardware, bit) in testList:
    print(testName)
    paths = "\\" + testName
    print paths
    addpath(paths)
    sys.modules[testName] = testName # One of a few options I've seen suggested on the net
    print("Path Added")
    test = testName + ".Helloworld()"
    eval(test)
```

So for each test I have, print the name, assemble a string which contains the path (`"\\testName"`), for this example, print the test path, then add the path to the list (`sys.path.append(path)`), then print to confirm it happened, then assemble a string which will be executed by `eval` for the tests main module and eventually eval it.

As you can see, I'm currently having to have a list of imports at the top. I can't simply do import `testName` (the contents of `testName` are the name of the module I wish to import), as it will try to find a module called `testName`, not a module called the contents of `testName`.

I've seen a few examples of where this has been done, but can't find any which work in my circumstances. If someone could literally throw a chunk of code which does it that would be wonderful.

I'd also request that I'm not hung, drawn, nor quartered for use of eval, it is used in a very controlled environment (the list through which it cycles is within the .py file, so no "end user" should mess with it).

Comment: Note that the indentation is correct in ST, for some reason I think this website just doesn't like parsing my text correctly :(

Comment: Don't use tabs but spaces for indentation.

Comment: Python already has a way of managing large collections of `.py` files that you might want to import, which understands folders and subfolders, lets you handle relative imports, does namespacing properly, and so on. It's called a [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Is there a reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: duplicate also of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Not sure if I understood everything correctly, but you can import a module dynamically using `__import__`:

```
mod = __import__(testName)
mod.HelloWorld()
```

**Edit**: I wasn't aware that the use of `__import__` was discouraged by the python docs for user code: [__import__ documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) (as noted by Bakuriu)

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) should also work and would be considered better style:

```
import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module(testName)
mod.HelloWorld()
```

Comment: Marvelous, thanks a ton for this, spent well over an hour scouring for information on it, I managed to write out __import__(testName) earlier, but didn't realise I had to assign the response to a module or w.e, fortunately all my functions will be named Test throughout all files, so I can just call mod.Test() from now on.

Comment: @XtrmJosh have you seen the other answer? `__import__` is an implementation detail; you should use `importlib` (or `imp` if you don't care about Python 3.x compatibility).

Comment: What kind of values are allowed for testName? Do I put `.py` at the end? Do I provide a relative path or an absolute path?

Comment: Aaron lead me to the solution to my problem. I added `.py` to `testName`. This does not work. Use your file name without extension!

Answer (score 24):

1. Never, ever, ever mess with `sys.modules` directly if you don't know exactly what you are doing.
2. There are a lot of ways to do what you want:

   1. The build-in [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) function
   2. Using [`imp.load_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module)
   3. Using [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

I'd avoid using `__import__` directly, and go for `importlib.import_module`(which is also suggested at the end of the documentation of `__import__`).

Comment: This is for `import moduleName` where moduleName is string. How about `from moduleName import *` ?

Comment: @NamGVU try to import the module as above and then: `globals().update(module.__dict__)`

Comment: I just found another solution here which import only the user-defined variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306598/248616

Comment: Where can I find examples of how to do this? I want to run methods defined in Python scripts in subfolders. Do I provide a relative path? Absolute path? Do I put a `.py` suffix?

Answer (score 3):

Add the path where module resides to sys.path. Import the module using __import__ function which accepts a string variable as module name.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, mypath)  # mypath = path of module to be imported
imported_module = __import__("string_module_name") # __import__ accepts string 
imported_module.myfunction()   # All symbols in mymodule are now available normally
```