# Import * from module by importing via string

Tags: python

I know I can use `importlib` to import modules via a string. How can I recreate the `import *` functionality using this library? Basically, I want something like this:

```
importlib.import_module('path.to.module', '*')
```

My reasons for not name-spacing the imported attributes are deliberate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution: import the module, then one by one make alias in the current namespace:

```
import importlib

# Import the module
mod = importlib.import_module('collections')

# Determine a list of names to copy to the current name space
names = getattr(mod, '__all__', [n for n in dir(mod) if not n.startswith('_')])

# Copy those names into the current name space
g = globals()
for name in names:
    g[name] = getattr(mod, name)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is shorten version for [@HaiVu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306598/248616) which refers to [this solution from @Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name/14071252?noredirect=1#comment75519547_14071252)

```
import importlib

# import the module
mod = importlib.import_module('collections')

# make the variable global
globals().update(mod.__dict__)
```

Note:

- This will import lots of things beside the user-defined variables
- @HaiVu solution did the best of it ie. only import user-defined variables