# recursive search for python scripts

Tags: python, linux, command-line, path

Say I have the following tree:

```
~/python
  ├── one
      └── toto.py
  └── two
      └── toto.py
```

Even after `export PATH=$PATH:~/python`, I can't seem to be able to run `python one/toto.py` and `python two/toto.py` from anywhere else than `~`. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: it's looking for the file from your current directory

Comment: File "opens" doesn't not coexist within the same rule set as file executions. To open a file you will need at the very least a relative path like `~/python/one/toto.py`. the `$PATH` variable is parsed by the shell itself when trying to find executables. You could create a python script that you mark as executable that tries to do this for you. by using `os.path.abspath(...)` to and use `sys.path` to find modules that it can import and "hand over" to.

Comment: The `PATH` variable will only affect where the shell finds the executable, `python` in your case.  It doesn't affect where `python` will look for files to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments.

`$PATH` in Linux is used to find a executable. In this case that's `Python`.
After this executable is found, it will be executed "in" the current working directory and work from there.

Meaning when `Python` gets the parameter `one/toto.py` it will start looking from `./` after your folder and file.

You could create a wrapper script, place that under `/usr/bin/mywrap.py`, mark it as a executable and utilize `for path in sys.path:` and try to find your module and dynamically import it and do a "hand over" to it.

There is no magic in the `Python` binary that will travers `$PATH` since this is a shell variable used to find binaries in the operating system. Much like `PATH` in windows is used for the same purpose.

- [Import file using string as name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name)

Answer (score 3):

One way you might be able to accomplish what you want is to use `PYTHONPATH` instead of `PATH`.  Then, you can tell the interpreter to run a module instead of the script directly.  For example:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/python
$ python -m one.toto
$ python -m two.toto
```

Note that we don't include the extension and the separator has changed from `/` to `.` because we're now dealing with python modules, not filesystem paths.