# How to create subparser with argparse from existing program in Python 3?

Tags: python, command-line, executable, argparse, subparsers

## Original post:

If one has an executable `mini_program.py` that uses `argparse` with the following structure:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-X', '--attribute_matrix', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--target_vector', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    opts = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can one create a controller program `parent_program.py` that uses `argparse` (I think with `subparser`?) to have a similar usage to below:

```
python parent_program.py --help

blah-blah list of programs that can be used
```

then using the subprogram:

```
python parent_program.py mini_program --help

-X description
-y description
etc...
```

How could all of the parameters propagate up from `mini_program.py` to the `parent_program.py`?

### EDIT (More specific with error message):

#### The program

```
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Subprograms
    subprograms = parser.add_subparsers(title="subprograms")
    # ============
    # mini-program
    # ============
    parser_miniprogram = subprograms.add_parser("miniprogram")

    # Input
    parser_miniprogram.add_argument('-X', '--attribute_matrix', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    parser_miniprogram.add_argument('-y', '--target_vector', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    opts = parser.parse_args()
    opts_miniprogram = parser_miniprogram.parse_args()
    print(opts_miniprogram.__dict__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Checking to make sure the docs work

```
# parent program
python parent_program.py --help
usage: parent_program.py [-h] {miniprogram} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit

subprograms:
  {miniprogram}

# miniprogram
python parent_program.py miniprogram --help
usage: parent_program.py miniprogram [-h] [-X ATTRIBUTE_MATRIX]
                                     [-y TARGET_VECTOR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -X ATTRIBUTE_MATRIX, --attribute_matrix ATTRIBUTE_MATRIX
                        Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv
  -y TARGET_VECTOR, --target_vector TARGET_VECTOR
                        Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv
```

#### Trying to run it:

```
python parent_program.py miniprogram -X ../../Data/X_iris.noise_100.tsv.gz -y ../../Data/y_iris.tsv
usage: parent_program.py miniprogram [-h] [-X ATTRIBUTE_MATRIX]
                                     [-y TARGET_VECTOR]
parent_program.py miniprogram: error: unrecognized arguments: miniprogram
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/03/21/python-multilevel-argparse.html) is useful. Or, as you mentioned, using [subparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448200/how-to-parse-multiple-nested-sub-commands-using-python-argparse).

Comment: @pazitos10 that git example is really interesting.  I've never seen argparse used int hat way.  I tried the subparser way and edited my answer.

Comment: You don't need to call: `parser_miniprogram.parse_args()`.  The subparser mechanism in `parser` takes care of invoking the subparser with remaining arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent program could have code like

```
import mini_program
import sys
<do its own parsing>
if 'use_mini':
    <modify sys.argv>
    mini_program.main()
```

As written, importing `mini_program` doesn't run its parser.  But calling its `main` will, but using the list it finds in `sys.argv`.

The parent parser should be written in a way that it accepts arguments that it needs, and doesn't choke on inputs the `mini` wants, '-X' and '-y'.  It would then puts those 'extra' values in a modified `sys.argv`, which the `mini` parser can handle.

`parse_known_args` is one way of accepting unknown arguments, 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing

`nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs, is another way of collecting remaining arguments for passing on.

If `mini` `main` was written as:

```
def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-X', '--attribute_matrix', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--target_vector', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    opts = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

it could be called with

```
mini_program.main(['-X', 'astring','-y','another'])
```

that is, with an explicit `argv` list, instead of working through `sys.argv`.

Keeping the main parser from responding to a '-h' help could be tricky.  `subparsers` is probably the cleanest way of doing that.

You could combine subparsers with the invocation of a the `mini` `main`.  I won't try to work out those details now.

Another way to define the `main` is:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-X', '--attribute_matrix', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--target_vector', type=str, help = 'Input: Path/to/Tab-separated-value.tsv')
    return parser
```

And use it as

```
 opts = main().parse_args()
 opts = mini_program.main().parse_args()
```

in other words, use `main` to define the parser, but delay the parsing.

Comment: Used this in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name

Answer (score 0):

My actual solution was an adaptation to the above:

```
# Controller
def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="parent_program", add_help=True)
    parser.add_argument("subprogram")
    opts = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return opts.subprogram


# Initialize
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the subprogram 
    subprogram = main([sys.argv[1]])
    module = importlib.import_module(subprogram)
    module.main(sys.argv[2:])
```