# How to list all classes and methods/functions in a specific .py file?

Tags: python

Let's say we have two python files (say, `file_1.py` and `file_2.py`), with the following structure:

```
-- file_1.py
      # file_1.py imports file_2
      fo(x) # a function
      A  # a class
          fun(y) # some method
          _bo(y) # some "hidden" method
-- file2.py
      bar(x) # a function
```

I would like some function like `get_functions_and_methods('file_1.py')` with an output like this:

```
'fo(x)', 'a.fun(y)', 'a._bo(y)'
```

Given that I'm a novice in Python, I have no idea how to go about constructing such information, and would be happy for help.

The closest I found online was:

- [How to list all classes and methods/functions in a package - with a full folder/file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73186008/how-to-list-all-classes-and-methods-functions-in-a-package-with-a-full-folder) which solves this for a module, but I can't seem to adjust it to .py files. I tried importing the .py file using `__import__` (from here: [Import file using string as name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name)), it didn't seem to work. The issue is that I don't just want to capture all of the def, but also connect them to classes if they are embedded within them.

How should I go about solving this? Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to be a combination of [How to list all functions in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-module) and [Import file using string as name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name) - can you show what specifically the problem was when you tried to use these solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a python file with following members

**file1.py**

```
def fo(x):
    pass

class A:
    def fun(self, y):
        pass 
    
    def _bo(self, y):
        pass
        
    def NS(y, z):
        pass
        
class B:
    def foo(self, z):
        pass 
    
    def _bar(self, t):
        pass
```

Expected output would be :

```
fo(x), A.fun(self, y), A._bo(self, y), A.NS(y, z), B.foo(self, z), B._bar(self, t)
```

We can use `ast` module of python to read the python file and its members in its respective format.

###### Give your file path here

```
import ast
with open(filepath) as file:
    node = ast.parse(file.read())
```

###### Get all the function and classes

```
result = []
functions = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
classes = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]
```

###### Add the method to the result in the desired format

```
def show_info(functionNode):
    function_rep = ''
    function_rep = functionNode.name + '('

    for arg in functionNode.args.args:
        function_rep += arg.arg + ','

    function_rep = function_rep.rstrip(function_rep[-1])
    function_rep += ')'
    return function_rep
```

###### Add all functions to the result

```
for function in functions:
    result.append(show_info(function))
```

###### Add all the class methods to the result

```
for class_ in classes:
    methods = [n for n in class_.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
    for method in methods:
        result.append((class_.name + '.' + show_info(method)))
```

##### Output :

```
print(', '.join(result))
```

This gives us the expected result

```
fo(x), A.fun(self,y), A._bo(self,y), A.NS(y,z), B.foo(self,z), B._bar(self,t)
```

### TL;DR

To run everything at once, just change the filepath in the code below

```
import ast

with open(r'YOURPYTHONFILEPATH') as file:
    node = ast.parse(file.read())

def show_info(functionNode):
    function_rep = ''
    function_rep = functionNode.name + '('

    for arg in functionNode.args.args:
        function_rep += arg.arg + ','

    function_rep = function_rep.rstrip(function_rep[-1])
    function_rep += ')'
    return function_rep

result = []
functions = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
classes = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]

for function in functions:
    result.append(show_info(function))

for class_ in classes:
    methods = [n for n in class_.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
    for method in methods:
        result.append((class_.name + '.' + show_info(method)))

print(', '.join(result))
# This prints expected output
# fo(x), A.fun(self,y), A._bo(self,y), A.NS(y,z), B.foo(self,z), B._bar(self,t)
```