# Python--How to make method call specific .py scripts depending on method arguments?

Tags: python, parsing, methods, arguments

Say I have a function which takes two arguments: arg1, arg2. I want the function to then call arg1_arg2.py. Of course, the actual file wouldn't be called arg1_arg2.py. So, if the user inputs hello, hi as the arguments, the function will call hello_hi.py (more specifically, it instantiates a class located in hello_hi.py, but that is not important). I can't do this using %s, since I am dealing with files, not strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html):

```
import importlib

hello = importlib.import_module("hello_hi.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `importlib` [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable). Something like

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module("{}.py".format(your_str))
```

I think there's almost certainly a better way to do this though -- why not just put a toplevel `__init__.py` in your directory -- assume the directory is `myclasses` -- and then instantiate `getattr(myclasses, your_str).ClassName()` instead. `importlib` seems like the wrong way to go.