# from x(defined in program) import y(defined in program) python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, filenames

I need some assitance since I really have no idea how I can fix this:

x="test"

y="test2"

When I try to import y from x , it says that there is no file with the name "x"
(from x import y)

Is there any way to import test2 from test

where test2 is a variable inside the filename test

(The code I'm currently using)

```
start="trans" 

x= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]

while len(x) !=1:

    global begin

    del x[0]

    print(x[0])

    list_to_string= ''.join(x)

    start="start"+list_to_string[0]

    print(start)

else:

    print("stop")


from start import start
```

Thanks already :)

Comment: where is `test2` ?...and where is `test`? and what is `start`?..really lost here!

Comment: Or you mean to import `start` variable?..but from where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [import module from string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: @Khalil test is a .py file and test2 is list inside a .py file , I want to import test2 from the py file test in a new file but instead of importing like : from test import test2 I want from x import y where X = "test" and y = "test2"

Comment: I see no `test2` variable in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable for an `import` statement.

`from x import y` will try to find a module *literally called* `y`. In your case, that probably means you want a file in the same directory called `y.py`. It will then try to find a variable (including, eg, a function or class name) in that module which is literally called `x` - ie, you need to do something in that file like:

```
x = 5
```

or:

```
def x():
    return 5
```

If you really want to use a string variable here, then there *are* ways to do that (see, eg, [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)), but you probably don't need to do that here. It looks like you just want:

```
from test import test2
```