# loading class in Python from a string name

Tags: python, string, class

I have a series of Class names and want to check them all and them import them. how to do this:

```
CName='Class_blahblah'
from eval(CName) import *
```

this is what I got:

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To be exact: I have couple of classes I run in IDE in a FEA software and I do for each of them something like this:

```
if 'Class_SetSurfPart' in sys.modules:  
    del sys.modules['Class_SetSurfPart']
    print 'old module Class_SetSurfPart deleted'
    from Class_SetSurfPart import *
    reload(sys.modules['Class_SetSurfPart'])
else:
    from Class_SetSurfPart import *
```

but I want to put all class names in a List and do this as loop instead of doing this for all Classes.

Comment: Is this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8719100/2599266) what you're looking for?

Comment: No, lets say `i=__import__('dupList', fromlist=[''])` and I get `>>> i` so I get `<module 'dupList' from 'D:\\My Pythons\dupList.py'>`. and error I get is `>>> dupList([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3])` and `NameError: name 'dupList' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to put the keys for

```
sys.modules
```

in a list like so:

```
keys = [key for key in sys.modules]
```

Remember that each item is stored as a string type.

```
#I'm assuming that you've already made a list of the classes you want to be 
#checking for in a list. I'll call that list classes.
for name in classes:
    if name in keys:
        del sys.modules[name]  #remember that this does not delete it permanently.
        print "Old module {} deleted".format(name)
        name = __import__(name)
        reload(name)
    else:
        __import__(name)
```

Comment: this did not work. it says imported by does not work.

Comment: What's the name of the module you are trying to import? Also, make sure there's no file extension(.py, .txt, etc.) on the file.

Comment: there are around Classes that I want to load as a loop. One of them is `Class_VerticesEdgesPart`.

Comment: `if 'Class_SetSurfPart' in sys.modules:  
    del sys.modules['Class_SetSurfPart']
    print 'old module Class_SetSurfPart deleted'
    from Class_SetSurfPart import *
    reload(sys.modules['Class_SetSurfPart'])
else:
    from Class_SetSurfPart import *`

Comment: What is the point of the reload function? Simply using del on sys.modules won't change it permanently.

Comment: I edited the question at the top so you can see what I am trying to do. I have number of classes that I have to check if they are already in memory or not and then load them. I want to reduce the number of lines I am using by using a sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want `importlib.import_module`:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imps$ ls pack/
__init__.py  stuff.py  
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imps$ cat pack/stuff.py
class Foo(object):
    pass
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imps$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
>>> import importlib
>>> module = importlib.import_module("pack.stuff")
>>> module
<module 'pack.stuff' from 'pack/stuff.pyc'>
>>> # now you can either use getattr() or directly refer to `module.Foo`: 
>>> cls = getattr(module, "Foo")
>>> cls
<class 'pack.stuff.Foo'>
>>> module.Foo
<class 'pack.stuff.Foo'>
>>> module.Foo is cls
True
```

Comment: it loads the module but when I run the module this way it gets error inside the module whereas when I load the module normally using from Class_mmm import * it works just fine.

Comment: "star imports" (`from module import *`) are BAD, one should never use them in production code (really, been here done that etc) - consider this "feature" as just a handy shortcut when trying out things in the Python shell -, so just do what you should have done anyway: either use the qualified path (ie `module.Foo` instead of `Foo`) or explicitely bind the names in your namespace (ie: `Foo = module.Foo`)