# call function from list(string) in another py file

Tags: python, maya

i have 3 python scripts ('testPrint01.py','testPrint02.py','testPrint03.py')
and i would like to call function from 'testPrint02'

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append(path)

    a = ['testPrint01','testPrint02','testPrint03']
    import sys.a[1]
    a[1].justPrintIt()
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the same directory as your target script you can use

```
from testPrint02 import x
```

Where x is the function you want to import.

**Edit**:
To import a module from a string variable you can use `importlib` as described here: [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: Hi imant, thank you for the answer, but what i wanna ask is how to import/ call another script from the string, because i try to create a script to call all my script (choose one of the script from the list, and click button to run it)

Comment: For this you might want to use importlib:
`from importlib import import_module`, `i = import_module(a[1])`. You can then use `i.justPrintIt()`.

Comment: oh thank you imant, its working :D