# Variables in import statement python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a script I had from bash to python. The way the program worked is that it had a Master script in the top folder and then in the subfolder Scripts a series of smaller, more specialised scripts. These smaller scripts might have names such as foo_bar.x, bar_foo.x, foo_baz.x, foo_qux.x, bar_qux.x, and so on. The Master script would collect the variables (as defined in files or from command line arguments) and execute the appropriate script with this sort of syntax:

```
VAR1=foo
VAR2=bar
./Scripts/${VAR1}_${VAR2}.x
```

This would execute Scripts/foo_bar.x

Now I'm trying to do the same but in python. The scripts are now modules in the folder Modules named foo_bar.py, foo_qux.py and so on. For now, the only thing they have is:

```
def test():
        print "This is foo_bar."
```

(or whichever).

If use these commands, this happens:

```
>>> import Modules.foo_bar
>>> Modules.foo_bar.test()
This is foo_bar.
>>> import Modules.foo_qux
>>> Modules.foo_qux.test()
This is foo_qux.
>>> a = Modules.foo_bar
>>> a.test()
This is foo_bar.
```

Which is fine. However, I can't get the syntax right if I want to use variables in the import statement. The first variable is defined as the string output of a command, and the second is a dictionary entry. Trying to use them in an import command gives an error.

```
>>> var1 = a_file.read_value()
>>> print var1
foo
>>> print dict['var2']
bar
>>> import Modules.var1_dict['var2']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import Modules.var1_dict['var2']
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I assume it's a question of having the correct quotes or parentheses to properly invoke the variables. I've tried a bunch of combinations involving single quotes, curly brackets, square brackets, whatever, but no dice. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `importlib` library. And use like this:

```
...
import importlib
...

    function_call = 'Modules.' + var1 + dict['var2']
    function_call = importlib.import_module(function_call) 
    function_call.test()
```

Comment: This is close to working, but the importlib command should be

Comment: @PietroAronica, Yeah the method is `import_module`, but you got the idea ))).

Comment: `function_call = importlib.import_module(function_call)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a module whose name is in a variable, you need to use `__import__`.

For example, let's create a dictionary whose values are the names of modules:

```
>>> d = { 1:'re', 2:'numpy' }
```

Now, let's import one of them:

```
>>> x = __import__(d[1])
>>> x
<module 're' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>
```

We can use the module as long as we refer to it by the name we have given it:

```
>>> s='jerry'; x.sub('j', 'J', s)
'Jerry
```

And, to import the other:

```
>>> y = __import__(d[2])
>>> y
<module 'numpy' from '/home/jll/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
>>> y.array([1,3,2])
array([1, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about executing your import statement dynamically?

Dummy example :

```
d = {"a" : "path"}
exec("import os.%s"%d["a"])
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```