# Python: How to import a modul, whose value is given by a string?

Tags: python

This is a very beginners question.

I have code with error message:

```
a = "sqlite3"
b = pandas
import a
import b
```

How to change the code, but **NOT** use `import sqlite3` or `import pandas`, to get the correct results? Thanks.

Comment: I'm really really curious about why you want to do this. Please tell.

Comment: @klutt well, I was thinking how to make the codes with less import lines... Beginners think oft strange things. :-)

Comment: I see. 'Because I can' is always a valid reason. But I had a hard time finding any actual use.

Comment: Think of your `import` statements more as documentation than as code that could (let alone should) be refactored.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `importlib`, but I would think strongly about why you would need to do this.

```
import importlib

# Equivalent to import sqlite3 as somemodule
a = "sqlite3"
somemodule = importlib.import_module(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a very, very solid reason to import from a string, don't do it. It's a bad idea. Try to rework your code so that your script knows what libraries it needs to use. I don't know what you intend to do, but it's probably better to import both libraries and leave one unused rather than trying to import from a string.

People who really need this can try:

> > > importlib.import_module('string')

credit to gecco for his answer in [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)