# Python - programmatically import a Python package by name

Tags: python-2.7

I have several different repositories from which I need to programmatically import a package with a common name, say `my_package`, e..g `/foo/bar/my_package` and `/foo/baz/my_package`. I need to be able to retrieve `my_package` from these different repositories and keep them in separate variables.

I've tried to do this with `importlib.import_module` but it just does not work - I end up with the same package variable.

```
os.chdir('/foo/bar')
foobar_my_package = importlib.import_module('my_package')

os.chdir('/foo/baz')
foobaz_my_package = importlib.import_module('my_package')

> foobar_my_package == foobaz_my_package
> True
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: try `foobar_my_package is foobaz_my_package`

Comment: It returns `True`.

Comment: It seems on the first call of`importlib.import_module('my_package')` this value is cached and the subsequent call yields the same value.

Comment: Maybe this works

`import imp
foobar_my_package = imp.load_source('/foo/bar/my_package', '/foo/bar/my_package.py')
foobaz_my_package = imp.load_source('/foo/baz/my_package', '/foo/baz/my_package.py')`

Comment: well, it is the same package. Try import another pacakge

Comment: `importlib` does not take account of the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no module named `my_package`, it is just a package name, the modules contained inside have different names.

Comment: `/foo/bar/my_package` will have different content compared with `/foo/baz/my_package` - the package names are the same but the content is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: I need a reference to the package not the modules inside.

Comment: You get an error, don't you? If you do, would you mind posting it here (in question).

Comment: I don't really get an error, but I keep getting a reference to the same object for both `/foo/bar/my_package` and `/foo/baz/my_package` - these are packages with the same name but different content. I need to be able to have different variables for these packages. I am not interested in the modules inside, just the packages.

Comment: I assumed `importlib.import_module` would also work for packages, that's why I used it, but clearly it does not work and there appears to be no way of getting references to packages as opposed to modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import imp

def myImporter(num, p):
    tup = imp.find_module('__init__', [p])
    module = imp.load_module('package%s' % i, *tup)
    tup[0].close()
    return module


if __name__ == '__main__':
    packages =  {}
    for i, p in enumerate(['/tmp/bar/my_package', '/tmp/foo/my_package']):
        _name = 'package%d' % i
        _module = myImporter(i, p)
        packages[_name] = _module

    for k,v in packages.items():
        print (v.__name__, v.main())
```

For the following directory structure:

```
.
├── bar
│   └── my_package
│       └── __init__.py
├── foo
│   └── my_package
│       └── __init__.py
```

Each `__init__.py` has a main() function:

```
def main():
        return "<name>/my_package/main"
```

It returns:

```
('package0', 'bar/my_package/main')
('package1', 'foo/my_package/main')
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it and let know.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately - it is complaining about a relative import in a non-package, i.e. the `__init__.py` in one of the packages.

Comment: You can try to add `sys.path.append(p)` in `myImporter()` before `find_module()`. Elsewise you need to provide more information to your question ...