# Import modules dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable), but I haven't been able to apply any of the given answers.

I have several test scripts, all using the same function implemented in a common file.

The common file begins with the following `import` statements:

```
from Class1       import          Class1
from Class2       import Type1 as Class2
from Class3       import Type1 as Class3
from Class4       import          Class4
from Class5.Type1 import          Class5
from Class6.Type1 import          Class6
```

I'd like to be able to change `Type1` for some of the test scripts.

At present, I just take the relevant statements out of the common file, and place them in each one of the test files with the type which is to be tested.

But I am looking for a "nicer" way, for example, pass a string which represents the type, and import dynamically according to that input string.

This would allow me to minimize the test scripts.

I guess I would probably need to place the `import` statement inside the function called by the test scripts, but I'm fine with that.

How exactly can I achieve this?

I haven't tried the infamously known `eval` because:

1. It is evil
2. I'm pretty sure that it doesn't work for "non-read-only" expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `importlib` module

```
import importlib

type_str = function_that_determines_this_val()
module = importlib.import_module(module)
obj = getattr(module, type_str)
```

Not sure this is exactly what you're looking for but `importlib` is probably what you're looking for.