# Python globally import in a for loop (preferrably Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-3.7

My code is this:

```
for module in ["ffmpy","os","sys"]:
    try:
        __import__(module)
    except:
        print("Can't import ["+module+"]")
```

So, I want to import this globally, but it doesn't seem to do this. After this code, I have `sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\david\Desktop\scripts")`,and the python console tells me: `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but you hopefully do.

edit: This Question is not a duplicate, because i don't 'just' want to import from string, but do that from a for loop. I basically want to import from a string, in a loop, globally.

Comment: I can see why you might want to conditionally handle importing of `ffmpy`, but `os` and `sys`…?! If those don't exist… then what?!

Comment: @deceze I think the question is interesting even without the `try-except` block.

Comment: @deceze Well I did that because of lazy programming, but I get your point. I just wrote everything to import in that line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: Well, don't be lazy.  It's *good* that `import` raises exceptions if things can't be imported, and you would need a really good reason to want to suppress those.

Comment: The module has been imported but not bound to the name `sys` in your scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is that although you have imported the library `sys` you haven't defined the object `sys`.

Consider the two following examples:

```
# Doesn't work
__import__('sys')
sys.callstats()
```

This throws the same error: "name 'sys' is not defined", while

```
# Works
sys = __import__('sys')
sys.callstats()
```

works fine.

You need to store the imported objects somewhere. A dictionary seems sensible:

```
import_dict = dict()

for module in ["ffmpy","os","sys"]:
    try:
        import_dict[module] = __import__(module)
    except:
        print("Can't import ["+module+"]")


import_dict['sys'].path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\david\Desktop\scripts")
```

Should work.

Edit:

As suggested by @9769953 in the comments, an even better solution is to use:

```
globals()[module] = __import__(module)
```

which then allows you to access `sys` directly as you would normally.

Comment: Or if you really want, use `globals()[module] = __import__(module)` and then use `sys` and others directly, as in `sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\david\Desktop\scripts")`.