# import module within python lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Is it possible to import module within a python lambda function? For example, i have a lambda function which requires to `import math`

```py
import math
is_na_yes_no = lambda x: 'Yes' if math.isnan(x) else 'No'
```

How can I include the `import math` statement within the lambda function?

To clarify, I have a scenario that need to put some lambda functions in a config file and evaluate the function in some other python files, exmample:

```
{
  "is_na_yes_no" = "lambda x: 'Yes' if math.isnan(x) else 'No'"
}
```

In this case, the python file that evaluating those lambda functions need to  all modules required.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: so for each iterable you want to import again and again, this is bad

Comment: @aran-fey i want to add flexibility to my code by putting some lambda functions in a config file, but issue is that the python file executing those lambda functions must know what modules to import

Comment: @Sayse it is not a XY problem, but i have a scenario it does not work

Comment: @prashantrana - No iterables involved here. OP, You don't need a lambda here at all, just define the function and import that to other modules that would use it.

Comment: You may be able to use importlib [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable/8719100) to create a lambda to import from a string, but id say its highly inadvisable to do so

Comment: Yay codegolfing.. `lambda x:'Yes'if __import__('math').isnan(x)else'No'`

Comment: Why do they have to be lambda functions? Why can't they be real functions?

Comment: @Aran-Fey because my code is storing the functions as string in a json file, which is user-configurable. please let me know if you have other suggestions

Comment: You can call an extra function in your lambda which imports a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @L3viathan for the answer.

Here is same thing without having to `import math` in the module.

```
is_na_yes_no = lambda x: 'Yes' if __import__('math').isnan(x) else 'No'
```

It highlights the flexibility of python -- `__import__` feature can be used in lambda functions instead of having them written out before hand.