# How to extract specific dictionary from python file by opening in python code

Tags: python

**I have the below python file "source.py", which is having dictionary(default_args) in it. I would like to extract only default_args dictionary from another python file "destination.py"**

## source.py:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import os

default_args = {
    'owner': 'kumar',
    'team': 'data_engineering',
    'start_date': timezone.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=LOCAL_TZ),
    'provide_context': True,
    'environment': ENV,
    'email': 'venkatsiva789@gmail.com',
    'email_on_failure': True,
}
```

**destination.py:**

```
 text = open("source.py").read()
print(text)
```

I want to extract only the below code snippet.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'kumar',
    'team': 'data_engineering',
    'start_date': timezone.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=LOCAL_TZ),
    'provide_context': True,
    'environment': ENV,
    'email': 'venkatsiva789@gmail.com',
    'email_on_failure': True,
}
```

Please help to extract the above code snippet or let me know is there any built in module to extract specific dictionary.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot import the module and access the dictionary like `from source import default_args`?

Comment: because, I get this file name as an argument with absolute path like "c://python/test/source.py"

Comment: You _can_ [import a module given its full path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631/1782792). If you still do not want to import it (e.g. you do not want to run the code in it), you can grab the value of that assignment easily with the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module. However, since the value is not made of just literals (has a function call and and `ENV` variable, which I'm not sure where is defined), you will not be able to get the value without actually running its code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have another file `main.py` where you want this dictionary, so:

```
# main.py

import source  # full path if needed

default_args = source.default_args
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I do not want to import the file, I need to open the file from the system and extract the specific part.

Comment: Why? You can import at any point fo your code, so why read it in instead of just importing?

Comment: @shiva if you read it as text, that's an unuseful piece of text, that's not a valid json, and you will have to use `eval` to use it as `dict`, so why?

Comment: I want dict object or else if i extract complete dictionary as a string then I can convert it to dict.

Comment: @shiva if you import and do `default_args = source.default_args` you have the complete dict

Comment: because, I get this file name as an argument with absolute path like "c://python/test/source.py"

Comment: you can still [import a module given the full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable

Comment: @shiva import_module will do the trick https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as a dict see @Gocht's answer. If you want it as a string you could use regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r'default_args(?:.|\s)+}', text)
```

Comment: it is extracting only default_args line like "{", I want complete dictionary.

Comment: output of above regex: ['{']

Comment: Please see edit, my fault, it was only returning the capture group

Comment: its working, but the cursor should stop at the end of the dictionary. Its loading full file as string