# Loop through list of lists to generate modules to import

Tags: python, nested-lists

The below code works great to print out what i am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
MODULES = [
['termcolor','colored','cprint'],
['signal','signal','SIGINT'],
['some_other_mod','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']
]

for ITEM in MODULES:
        print("from",'{0} import {1}'.format(ITEM[0],', '.join(str(i) for i in ITEM[1:]))))
```

When I run the script, it's printed nicely, but unsure how to make it actually do it.

```
$ ./script.py
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from signal import signal, SIGINT
from some_other_mod import one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight
```

Using exec() with printed format doesn't seem to work.
You can see what I am trying to do. If I can list/loop through to import the modules, it would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: What do you mean by exec doesn't work? Did you run `exec(print(...)) `?

Comment: Did you try having a look at importlib?

Comment: As this question is closed I have added answer in the existing question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60034522/3129414

Comment: @mistermiyagi I'd get a 'TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object' error. The links provided in comments fixed the syntax though. Thanks all.