# importing a module with a user inputted name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is what I have been trying to use:

```
filename = str(input("Enter a file name: "))
file = filename.split('.')
file = file[0]
from file import *
```

However, the interpreter doesn't attempt to look for the variable assigned to file, and looks for a module named 'file' does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might work for you:

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(filename.split('.')[0])
```

Then you should be able to use `module` in order to call any of the imported functions.

Comment: Edit: I misunderstood, you were perfectly correct, thank you!