# python string to a function call with arguments, without using eval

Tags: python, python-import, eval

I have a string stored in a database stands for a class instance creation for example `module1.CustomHandler(filename="abc.csv", mode="rb")`, where CustomHandler is a class defined in module1.

I would like to evaluate this string to create a class instance for a one time use. Right now I am using something like this

```py
statement = r'module1.CustomHandler(filename="abc.csv", mode="rb")'  # actually read from db
exec(f'from parent.module import {statement.split(".")[0]}')
func_or_instance = eval(statement)  # this is what I need
```

Only knowledgable developers can insert such records into database so I am not worried about `eval` some unwanted codes. But I've read several posts saying `eval` is unsafe and there is always a better way. Is there a way I can achieve this without using `eval`?

Comment: This is a bad idea to begin with. You're essentially storing code which needs to be evaluated as code. Storing code as data is bad, because it ties data to a specific implementation. This makes your actual code inflexible, since you can't rearrange or rename it without also needing to update everything in your database that refers to it. It would be better to store this in the database in a more neutral format, which can be parsed and translated to actual function calls in a controlled way; e.g.: `{"action": "custom", "kwargs": {"filename": "abc.csv", "mode": "rb"}}`.

Comment: @deceze I totally agree, however I am only doing changes to the code and cannot modify how it actually runs underneath.

Comment: the `ast` module is only recommended when you can use `literal_eval` (safer because it doesn't execute code), or when you actually want to inspect the tree that you get, before you execute the code. -- eval() is **unsafe** _not_ because it might throw exceptions, but because it can execute whatever code you give it... which might be code __others__ give you, and they might have bad intentions (vulnerability)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: a proper import, instead of exec() would be a lot safer. please check out the question I linked to.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the detailed info, as I mentioned, my case is probably special because the project will be only internally used by developers who know a good deal of python. Moreover, after the statement is read from db, we do some inspections to make sure it's most likely to be what we need. The post doesn't help because the function comes with arguments. I understand that I can store them in a different way and construct the function in a safer way, this is planned for the next major version. Can you please show me an example if you think importlib can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `ast` Python module, which stands for abstract syntax trees. It's mainly used when you need to process the grammar of the programming language, work with code in string format, and so much more functions available in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

- In this case `eval()` function looks like the best solution, clear and readable, but safe only under certain conditions. For example, if you try to evaluate a code that contains a class not implemented in the code, it will throw an exception. That's the main reason why eval is sometimes unsafe.

Comment: Throwing an exception on unimplemented class is actually what's expected, targeting users are only developers so exceptions are not too ugly. I also read about `eval` is bad at performance (like run speed), should I worry about that?

Comment: @foocli I don't exactly know its performance against modules as `ast`. But you have its official documentation attached to know more about `ast`.

Comment: Roughly went through the `ast` documentation, just to make it clear, you meant that I can use `ast` to parse the statement string to get the function/class name, with arguments separately in a dict, so I can assemble the statement in a real python way. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @foocli Yes, `ast` can parse Python code