# How can I import a module as a parameter in a function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module, parameters

I try to import a module as a parameter in a function. But my PyCharm shows me a error:

#### Code

> #This program schow me all commands from a Modul ( for example os )
> def schow(name):
> import name
>
> ```
> a = list((str(dir(name))).split(","))
>
> for i in range(0, len(a)):
>     print(str(i) + a[i])
> ```
>
> schow(os)

#### Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/****/PyChrm/***/***/**.py", line 10, in 
> schow(os) NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable). 
You should check the [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module 

Answer (score 0):

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable), you're looking for the [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module.

You can do it like this:

```py
import importlib

# Single line import
importlib.import_module('itertools.combinations')

# Looping import
MODULES = {
    'typing': ['Optional', 'Union', 'List']
}
for (module, submodules) in MODULES.items():
    for submodule in submodules:
        importlib.import_module(f"{module}.{submodule}")
```

Or you can do it manually, like this:

```py
MODULES = {
    'itertools': ['combinations'],
    'typing': ['Optional', 'Union', 'List']
}

for (module, submodules) in MODULES.items():
    import_str = f"from {module} import {', '.join(submodules)}"
    exec(import_str)
```