# python sub-modules and path-names manipulation

Tags: python

Recent i was learning pathnames manipulation in python, having a basic understanding of modules the following statements confused me

`os` and `os.path` are both modules :( how is this possible

Then i looked at [os.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py) source code and found the following enlightening  line of code

```
57. import posixpath as path
```

My question are

Why should i use `os.path.join('bin','utils')` instead of `posixpath.join('bin','utils')` ?

What is the simples possible way to exlain `x` and `x.y` as both modules and when should i apply this technique?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724348/should-i-use-import-os-path-or-import-os- "The `os.path` name is an alias for this
module on Posix systems; on other systems (e.g. Mac, Windows),
`os.path` provides the same operations in a manner specific to that
platform, and is an alias to another module (e.g. macpath, ntpath)"

Comment: If you look at the context of that `import posixpath as path` you will see that it only happens if the script is running on a Posix system. `posixpath` is not intended to be used directly by normal user code, you should let `os` handle those details for you. Otherwise, your script won't work on non-Posix systems.

Comment: I posted the answer, thanks to @Chris_Rands and @PM 2Ring for pointing that out. Though someone can still use `posixpath` if knows exactly what he/she is doing otherwse `os.path` is the best choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.join('bin','utils')` instead of `posixpath.join('bin','utils')`

I discover that using `os.path` is more robust that using `posixpath` directly.

`os.path` offer compatibility with different operating system. Simplified code from [os.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py)

```
if 'posix' == os.name :
    from posix import *
    import posixpath as path
elif 'nt' == os.name :
    from nt import *
    import ntpath as path
....
```

As you can see using `os.path` will ensure you are manipulating path for the current os specifics.