# Confused why import os; os.environ['a'] = 'x'; import os.path raises UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Can someone explain why the following happens?  I had a look at [Should I use `import os.path` or `import os`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724348/should-i-use-import-os-path-or-import-os) which is informative, vaguely similar, but didn't really clarify it for me.

If I comment out `import os.path` or add it directly after `import os` there's no error.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.2
$ cat min.py
import os

def main():
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
    import os.path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
$ python min.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "min.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "min.py", line 4, in main
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
$
```

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect 'import os.path' counts as a write to `os` variable in local scope, so, `os` does not exist before that (which seems like a bug to me, that os is counted as an assignment here).  `os.path` should be the target of the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# assigns 'os' to global namespace
import os

def main():
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo' # <== which 'os'?  python assumes local
    # assigns 'os' to local namespace
    import os.path
```

`import` does two things.  First, it creates a module object. Second it gives a name to that newly created module object.  Giving something a name is assignment, hence the error message "`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment`".

Python has rules about the visibility of names and when they can be referenced.  One of the rules is that there cannot be ambiguity in a function as to whether you mean to refer to a local name or a global name.  If a local name is created anywhere inside a function that is the same as a global name, Python assumes that all references to that name inside the function refer to the local name (unless you specifically say otherwise).

Three possible fixes.

Drop the local import:

```
import os

def main():
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
```

Drop the global import and move local import to the top of the function

```
def main():
    import os.path 
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
```

Declare `os` global at the beginning of your function so that the first reference uses the global:

```
import os

def main():
    global os
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
    import os.path
```

A note about imports.

```
# has the same effect as 'import module'
# creates a reference named 'module'
import module.submodule

# imports submodule and creates a reference to it named 'submodule'
from module import submodule

# imports submodule and creates a reference to it named 'x'
import module.submodule as x
```

Answer (score 4):

Because an import is also an assignment. If you do `import os.path` in your main method, you're making `os` a *local* name, and Python won't look in the global scope to see the `os` you've already imported.

Comment: Very succinct.  You say in two sentences what took me ten.

Comment: Steve's correct that this is the bestest answer, but it took Steve's explanation to make me understand this in my head: "Python has rules about the visibility of names and when they can be referenced. One of the rules is that there cannot be ambiguity in a function as to whether you mean to refer to a local name or a global name. If a local name is created anywhere inside a function that is the same as a global name, Python assumes that all references to that name inside the function refer to the local name (unless you specifically say otherwise)."

Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I happens because you are trying to use the library 'os' before importing it.
You can do

```
def main():
    import os
    #now you can use os.environment
    os.environ['blah'] = 'bloo'
    #you don't need to import os.path as os is already imported


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's the `import os.path` after the assignment that is causing problems.  In your example, if I move `import os` to global scope everything's hunky dory.  I agree that I don't technically need to `import os.path` anyways, but am curious why it's a problem.