# Is it possible to generate import statement from the module object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, code-generation

In Python, it is easy to check if an object is a module with `isinstance(obj, types.ModuleType)`. We can also programmatically generate modules. I am however interested in going the other way around - generating code that would have created an import resulting in the module being added the globals/locals namespace. Basically a function `assemble_import` like this:

```
def assemble_import(module: types.ModuleType, name: str) -> str:
    pass
```

Roughly satisfying following conditions:

```
import statistics
assert assemble_import(statistics, 'statistics') = 'import statistics'

from os import path
assert assemble_import(path, 'path') = 'from os import path'

import collections.abc
abc = collections.abc
assert assemble_import(abc, 'abc') = 'from collections import abc'

import abc as xyz
assert assemble_import(xyz, 'xyz') = 'import abc as xyz'
```

I would **not** want it to use the abstract syntax tree, but rather the module object itself. What I have tried to so far:

- `module.__spec__` - it returns `ModuleSpec` with the name attribute
- `module.__package__` - not sure why but is empty most of the time
- `module.__loader__` - usually `SourceFileLoader`, also has the name attribute

the problem with the name attribute is that it is 'posixpath' for `os.path`, while `from os import posixpath` clearly does not work. Also, I do not see how to get the parent module (`os` in the `os.path` example).

Is achieving a workable (though not necessarily a production-ready/bulletproof) solution possible in Python? In other words, is the information about packages structure needed to recreate the imports code preserved/accessible?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve by that? Are you aware of https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am aware. I do not want to manipulate my custom modules, but any user-provided module and I am curious if achieving code generation from the objects is possible with Python.

Comment: I don't understand yet: In `assert assemble_import(xyz, 'xyz') = 'import abc as xyz'`, where should `abc` come from in the output?

Comment: From the module object. `xyz` is aliased `abc` (`import abc as xyz`).

Comment: The second argument is provided from globals/locals dict (and is the name of the variable, which generally cannot be obtained from the object itself).

Comment: An example use of this would be in a re-implementation of https://github.com/microsoft/gather (or any other program which does dynamic code generation from the user input). The current implementation stores every line ever executed and attempts to re-create a workable subprogram with trial-and-error subsetting (well, not really, but this is the idea). The code generated this way can be suboptimal (see `import os; sys = os.sys`), and this implementation is leaking memory in a sense (storing every line ever executed). Static analysis and AST would be a way out, but this question is not about it.

Comment: You're not going to get what you want for `os.path` unless you add a special case, because `os.path` is weird - it's really the `ntpath` or `posixpath` module, depending on your platform. `os.path` is just a platform-dependent alias.

Comment: Your desired output for `os.sys` is just bizarre. `os.sys` is not an expression you should ever write - `os` happens to import the `sys` module, and that does make `sys` an accessible attribute on the `os` module, but this is an implementation detail you should never rely on, and there's no point in relying on it. Just `import sys` through its actual name.

Comment: Agreed, but these are just examples that I used to demonstrate the idea, could have used os.path or something else again.

Comment: `os.path` is unique and idiosyncratic in a way that modules are normally not supposed to be - it probably would not have been designed that way if it wasn't such an early part of Python. If you really want to treat it as `os.path` instead of `posixpath` or `ntpath`, your best bet is a special case.

Comment: Is `collections.abc` different from `os.path`? This was introduced in 3.3.

Comment: `collections.abc` is quite different from `os.path`. It's an actual submodule of an actual `collections` package, and it's the same module on all platforms, rather than being a platform-dependent alias.

Comment: I see. `abc.__package__ == 'collections'` while `path.__package__ == ''`. The observation that `os.path` (which I was using as a toy example) is just weird and could be treated as a special case mostly solves this question. Do you have a reference to support that `os.path` is unique in its weirdness?

Comment: Not really. I can point to the [tutorial section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on packages, and I can point to how [the `os` module and its way of setting up `os.path` looks nothing like that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/os.py#L48-L93), and you can go look at a bunch of other packages that look nothing like what `os` does.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724348/should-i-use-import-os-path-or-import-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and it's quite straightforward, but `os.path` will be a little weird:

```
def assemble_import(module, name):
    return 'import {} as {}'.format(module.__name__, name)
```

`os.path` is weird because it's a platform-dependent alias for either the `ntpath` module or the `posixpath` module. This function will use the module's actual name, either `ntpath` or `posixpath`. If you want to treat `os.path` as `os.path`, you can special-case it, though it might not be the best design choice.

For *actual* package submodules, like `collections.abc`, this function will treat them as submodules of their containing package:

```
>>> assemble_import(collections.abc, 'abc')
'import collections.abc as abc'
```

but for `os.path`, this will give you output like

```
>>> assemble_import(os.path, 'path')
'import posixpath as path'
```

---

If you want imports that look a bit more like what a human would normally write, you can add some logic to the function:

```
def assemble_import(module, name):
    pname, _, mname = module.__name__.rpartition('.')
    if pname:
       statement = 'from {} import {}'.format(pname, mname)
    else:
       statement = 'import ' + mname
    if mname != name:
       statement += ' as ' + name
    return statement
```