# Why do you only sometimes need to import submodules?

Tags: python

I think a code example would make this most clear:

```py
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2022, 08:48:06) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists('/').  // importing submodule is not necessary
True
>>> import unittest
>>> unittest.mock.MagicMock().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'unittest' has no attribute 'mock'
>>> import unittest.mock.  // importing submodule *is* necessary here
>>> unittest.mock.MagicMock()
<MagicMock id='4314421952'>
```

For `unittest.mock`, I needed to import the submodule, but this wasn't the case for `os.path`. What's the underlying mechanism that determines when this works? Does this have to do with namespace packages?

More broadly, when does Python search for submodules? [This blog post](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-11-how-the-python-import-system-works/) says:

> When Python sees that a module doesn't have a specified attribute, it considers the attribute to be a submodule and tries to import it. So if module defines func and Class but not submodule, Python will try to import module.submodule.

but I'm not certain how credible this is. If they are right, why doesn't that work for `unittest.mock`?

To whoever closed this question as a duplicate, the linked question doesn't answer how or when python searches for submodules (does it ever?). Also this applies to circumstances beyond `os.path`:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725195/7830612) explains that for importing `os` automatically adds `os.path` to `sys.modules`. I've experienced this in at least one other case as well however.

Using the [`cognitojwt`](https://pypi.org/project/cognitojwt/) package I found that I could run:

```py
>>> import cognitojwt
>>> cognitojwt.token_utils.get_unverified_claims
```

without raising an attribute error. I checked the `__init__.py` file, but didn't see any manual manipulation of `sys.modules` so I suspect there's something more going on.