Can I alias a python subpackage to be accessible from the top level package using dot notation?
This is probably a really basic packaging question, but I just haven't been able to find the answer.
TLDR: I want to know if it's possible to access a nested subpackage (located at mypackage.subpackage.target_package) by using the dot notation alias mypackage.target_package. i.e. can you add mypackage.target_package to the top level namespace of mypackage?
Full explanation:
I am developing a Python package that originally had the following structure:
mypackage
├── __init__.py
├── subpackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_b.py
└── target_package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module_c.py

In this way, target_package was accessible as follows: from mypackage.target_package import *. However, I am doing some refactoring and moving target_package into subpackage.
New structure:
mypackage
├── __init__.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module_b.py
    └── target_package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module_c.py

The problem is, I don't want to break backward compatibility with the former way of accessing the target_package, i.e. I want to be able to access mypackage.subpackage.target_package by simply calling mypackage.target_package
I've tried many different combinations of imports within the three _init_.py files and have only succeeded in making modules within target_package (like module_c) accessible at this level.
Currently, in the innermost _init_.py, the contents are
# mypackage/subpackage/target_package/__init__.py
from . import 

and within subpackage, the init file is blank
# mypackage/subpackage/__init__.py


and within the top level init of mypackage:
# mypackage/__init__.py
from .subpackage import target_package

With these in place, I can call
from mypackage import target_package
without any issues, but when I try to call
import mypackage.target_package
it throws a ModuleNotFound error.
Any advice? Is there a way to do what I am proposing? Is it against best practices? Should I give up on backwards compatibility?

This will handle from mypackage import target_package and import mypackage.target_package correctly but not import mypackage.target_package.module_c:
mypackage
├── __init__.py
├── target_package.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module_b.py
    └── target_package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module_c.py

In the target_package.py:
from .subpackage.target_package import *

In the innermost __init__.py:
# All the things you want to make available in target_package e.g.
from .module_c import some_function_in_module_c
...

So now, all of these will work:

from mypackage.target_package import mod_c_func
from mypackage import target_package
import mypackage.target_package

But none of these will:

from mypackage.target_package.module_c import mod_c_func
import mypackage.target_package.module_c

If you want the import mypackage.target_package.module_c to still work, you have 2 options:

Keep the mypackage.target_package as a package and change the files in there to import * from the corresponding 'real' module in mypackage.subpackage.target_package.
(Not recommended) You can try to insert mypackage.target_package into sys.modules (python actually internally does this for os.path) when any of your modules/packages are loaded, but for this to work, it would require that in the users' code, one of your other modules/packages is imported first and the import mypackage.target_package only happens after that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725195/19115554 for more details.


What do you mean by saying "In the target_package.py"? That isn't a file in my package.

You can create it, see the file structure diagram at the top of my answer

I see, I missed that on first reading. Is that an acceptable best practice though? Creating a python module of the same name on the upper level?

It shouldn't cause any problems if the target_package is now a file on the top level instead of a package (except for the fact that import mypackage.target_package.module_c will no longer work). I think the best practise will depend on how people are using that package and how big that subpackage is. For example, if a lot of people are using import mypackage.target_package.module_c, then it might be worth leaving all the files there but changing them to just import the functionality from the 'real' modules that are nested to avoid breaking things for those users.

Just to clarify, if you're keeping the mypackage.target_package as a package (the option 1 in my answer) and just importing the things from the 'real' implementation in the mypackage.subpackage.target_package, you don't need to add the target_package.py file.

For your answer 1., when you say "change the files in there" do you mean add a star import to module_c.py or the init.py or both in target_directory?

Both: in the module_c.py in mypackage.target_package, add from .subpackage.target_package.module_c import * and in the __init__py in mypackage.target_package add from .subpackage.target_package import *
