# How can I check the extension of a file?

Tags: python, file-extension

I'm working on a certain program where I need to do different things depending on the extension of the file. Could I just use this?

```
if m == *.mp3
   ...
elif m == *.flac
   ...
```

Comment: use python re module (regex) for matching

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 618, accepted):

Assuming `m` is a string, you can use `endswith`:

```
if m.endswith('.mp3'):
...
elif m.endswith('.flac'):
...
```

To be case-insensitive, and to eliminate a potentially large else-if chain:

```
m.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))
```

Comment: _ext = m.rpartition('.')[-1]; if ext ==_ will be much more efficient

Comment: @volcano why not use `.split('.')[-1]`? Or is rpartition really high efficiency?

Comment: @Stevoisiak, I think you misplaced your comment as this solution works even in the case you point out

Comment: This doesn't account for folder names with periods. `C:/folder.jpg` is a valid path. You can confirm if it is a file or folder with `os.path.isfile(m)`

Comment: @JayTuma Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed my comment

Comment: This isn't file type cheking, if some one change file format so that can makes bugs in program.

Answer (score 79):

`os.path` provides many functions for manipulating paths/filenames. ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html))

`os.path.splitext` takes a path and splits the file extension from the end of it.

```
import os

filepaths = ["/folder/soundfile.mp3", "folder1/folder/soundfile.flac"]

for fp in filepaths:
    # Split the extension from the path and normalise it to lowercase.
    ext = os.path.splitext(fp)[-1].lower()

    # Now we can simply use == to check for equality, no need for wildcards.
    if ext == ".mp3":
        print fp, "is an mp3!"
    elif ext == ".flac":
        print fp, "is a flac file!"
    else:
        print fp, "is an unknown file format."
```

**Gives:**

```
/folder/soundfile.mp3 is an mp3!
folder1/folder/soundfile.flac is a flac file!
```

Comment: This method ignores leading periods so `/.mp3` is not considered an mp3 file. This is however the way a leading space should be treated. E.g `.gitignore` is not a file format

Comment: This doesn't account for folder names with periods. (`C:/folder.jpg/file.mp3` is a valid path). You can exclude those with `os.path.isfile(m)`

Answer (score 77):

Use `pathlib` From Python3.4 onwards.

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('my_file.mp3').suffix == '.mp3'
```

---

If you are working with folders that contain periods, you can perform an extra check using

```
Path('your_folder.mp3').is_file() and Path('your_folder.mp3').suffix == '.mp3'
```

to ensure that a folder with a `.mp3` suffix is not interpreted to be an mp3 file.

Answer (score 21):

Look at module fnmatch.  That will do what you're trying to do.

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print file
```

Answer (score 9):

or perhaps:

```
from glob import glob
...
for files in glob('path/*.mp3'): 
  do something
for files in glob('path/*.flac'): 
  do something else
```

Answer (score 9):

one easy way could be:

```
import os

if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".mp3":
    # do something
```

`os.path.splitext(file)` will return a tuple with two values (the filename without extension + just the extension). The second index ([1]) will therefor give you just the extension. The cool thing is, that this way you can also access the filename pretty easily, if needed!

Answer (score 6):

An old thread, but may help future readers...

I would **avoid** using **.lower()** on filenames if for no other reason than to make your code more platform independent. (linux **is** case sensistive, **.lower()** on a filename will surely corrupt your logic eventually ...or worse, an important file!)

Why not use **re**?  (Although to be even more robust, you should check the magic file header of each file...
[How to check type of files without extensions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python) )

```
import re

def checkext(fname):   
    if re.search('\.mp3$',fname,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return('mp3')
    if re.search('\.flac$',fname,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return('flac')
    return('skip')

flist = ['myfile.mp3', 'myfile.MP3','myfile.mP3','myfile.mp4','myfile.flack','myfile.FLAC',
     'myfile.Mov','myfile.fLaC']

for f in flist:
    print "{} ==> {}".format(f,checkext(f))
```

Output:

```
myfile.mp3 ==> mp3
myfile.MP3 ==> mp3
myfile.mP3 ==> mp3
myfile.mp4 ==> skip
myfile.flack ==> skip
myfile.FLAC ==> flac
myfile.Mov ==> skip
myfile.fLaC ==> flac
```

Answer (score 6):

You should make sure the "file" isn't actually a folder before checking the extension. Some of the answers above don't account for folder names with periods. (`folder.mp3` is a valid folder name).

---

**Checking the extension of a file:**

```
import os

file_path = "C:/folder/file.mp3"
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
    if file_extension.lower() == ".mp3":
        print("It's an mp3")
    if file_extension.lower() == ".flac":
        print("It's a flac")
```

Output:

```
It's an mp3
```

---

**Checking the extension of all files in a folder:**

```
import os

directory = "C:/folder"
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
        print(file, "ends in", file_extension)
```

Output:

```
abc.txt ends in .txt
file.mp3 ends in .mp3
song.flac ends in .flac
```

---

**Comparing file extension against multiple types:**

```
import os

file_path = "C:/folder/file.mp3"
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
    if file_extension.lower() in {'.mp3', '.flac', '.ogg'}:
        print("It's a music file")
    elif file_extension.lower() in {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'}:
        print("It's an image file")
```

Output:

```
It's a music file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
source = ['test_sound.flac','ts.mp3']

for files in source:
   fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(files)
   print fileExtension   # Print File Extensions
   print fileName   # It print file name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import shutil, os

source = ['test_sound.flac','ts.mp3']

for files in source:
  fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(files)

  if fileExtension==".flac" :
    print 'This file is flac file %s' %files
  elif  fileExtension==".mp3":
    print 'This file is mp3 file %s' %files
  else:
    print 'Format is not valid'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (file.split(".")[1] == "mp3"):
    print "its mp3"
elif (file.split(".")[1] == "flac"):
    print "its flac"
else:
    print "not compat"
```

Comment: This won't work for files containing multiple `.`s, for example `some.test.file.mp3`

Comment: You could do [-1] to capture that edge case.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is uploaded then

```
import os


file= request.FILES['your_file_name']          #Your input file_name for your_file_name
ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[-1].lower()


if ext=='.mp3':
    #do something

elif ext=='.xls' or '.xlsx' or '.csv':
    #do something

else:
    #The uploaded file is not the required format
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file='test.xlsx'
if file.endswith('.csv'):
    print('file is CSV')
elif file.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print('file is excel')
else:
    print('none of them')
```

Comment: Describe something about your answer will help others to understand easily , refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised none of the answers proposed the use of the `pathlib` library.

Of course, its use is situational but when it comes to file handling or stats `pathlib` is gold.

Here's a snippet:

```py
import pathlib


def get_parts(p: str or pathlib.Path) -> None:
    p_ = pathlib.Path(p).expanduser().resolve()
    print(p_)
    print(f"file name: {p_.name}")
    print(f"file extension: {p_.suffix}")
    print(f"file extensions: {p_.suffixes}\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = 'conf/conf.yml'
    arch_file_path = 'export/lib.tar.gz'

    get_parts(p=file_path)
    get_parts(p=arch_file_path)
```

and the output:

```
/Users/hamster/temp/src/pro1/conf/conf.yml
file name: conf.yml
file extension: .yml
file extensions: ['.yml']

/Users/hamster/temp/src/pro1/conf/lib.tar.gz
file name: lib.tar.gz
file extension: .gz
file extensions: ['.tar', '.gz']
```