# Look at length of file type and determine what type of file is being opened

Tags: python, file, if-statement, range

working on a program that takes a file and determines what type it is. It must be a .wav or .jpg file to be correct, and if it is not one of those, it will display a message that says to choose a correct file type. However, I am stuck on how to get it to determine what type of file is being chosen, since for this program I am not allowed to use f.endswith(), so I was thinking range may work but I am unsure what the paramaters should be, or if range is even the correct choice for how to determine the file type. help please :)

```
def fileType():
  f = pickAFile
  print f
  for f in range ():
      start = f.rfind(".") 
      if start!=-1:

          print A .wav file type was selected

          print A .jpg file type was selected
      else:
          print No file type was chosen
          print Please choose a different file type
```

ok I have tried something like this but it is giving me a syntax error, could you help me with what the issue may be?

```
def fileType(): 
f = pickAFile 
print f f[f.rfind('.'):] 
  if f[f.rfind('.'):] == '.wav': 
    print "A sound file was selected." 
  if f[f.rfind('.'):] == '.jpg' : 
    print "An image file was selected 
  else: 
    print " This was an incorrect file type." 
    print " Please chose a .wav or .jpg file."
```

Comment: What language? You can either do an `EndsWith("wav")` or a substring of the file

Comment: @KevinMee it looks like Python, and the question says *"I am not allowed to use f.endswith()"*.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am unfamiliar with python, and since an EndsWith() wont work it seems like a substring is a good approach

Comment: yes its in python, but what do you mean when you say substring? I am suppossed to use something that tests the length of the file name, like len(f) and then find how long the end is before the '.' at the end

Comment: Names don't, in fact, define the type of a file. The actual contents of the file define the type. The [libmagic library and the file command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28Unix%29) have a database of heuristics for identifying file types.  (FYI)

Comment: @Lauren You can split the string on '.' , count the length and then check the extension. `string[] array = filename.Split('.');` then assuming the filename is something.ext you can get the length of `array[0]` and then compare `array[1]` to see if it is equal to `wav or jpg`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/checking-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

string slicing is what you are looking for, for example:

```
>>> s = 'file.wav'
>>> s[s.rfind('.'):]
'.wav'
```

`s[index:index2]` returns a copy of `s` that starts at `index` and ends, but does not include, all characters to `index2`

you can then do a check like:

```
s[s.rfind('.'):] == '.wav' # this statement is == s.endswith('.wav')
```

using string slicing

```
>>> s = 'file.wav'
>>> s[-3:]
'wav'
```

Comment: ok I have tried something like this but it is giving me a syntax error, could you help me with what the issue may be?

    def fileType():
     
      f = pickAFile
     
        print f
      f[f.rfind('.'):]
        if f[f.rfind('.'):] == '.wav':
          print "A sound file was selected.
        if f[f.rfind('.'):] == '.jpg' :
          print "An image file was selected
        else:
          print " This was an incorrect file type."
          print " Please chose a .wav or .jpg file."

Comment: i cant really help with syntax issues if its in the comments, maybe add an edit in your original post with the code

Comment: yes. but what is `PickAFile`? because if it is a method, it should have brackets

Comment: and your `print f f[f.rfind...` line should be `print f[f.rfind...]` (you have an extra `f`) I am also assuming your indent errors are just when you posted to SO

Comment: yes there should be brackets after pickAFile that was my error, i did not know there was indent errors what needs to be fixed? the main error its giving me is that the line "if f[f.rfind:]=='.wav':" is not legal jython so am i unsure how to fix that issue...

Comment: should be `f.rfind(',')`

Comment: no it is ('.') but what is not working is that it is not recongnizing the ending to be .wav or .jpg, is there a way i could just tell it that if the length of the ending of the file is 3 letters to print a statement?

Comment: sorry yes, that was supposed to be a `.`. well you can jsut string slice like `s[-3:] to get the last 3 characters, see above

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can use the  `contains` method. You  would  write it  something like this `FileVariable.contains("png")`, within an  if statement. These conditions  would not be statements. Let  me just write it out to be  clear.

```
if (!(FileVariable.contains("fileextension"))
     && !(FileVariable.contains("otherfileextension") {

    // if it  makes  it past this sort of  filter
    // then  it will only be using the  file types that you mention

}
```

You could also instead of saying each  one that can't be used  make a  filter that  tells  it what can be let through.  This would be much simpler.