# regular expression matching filename with multiple extensions

Tags: regex, filenames

Is there a regular expression to match the `some.prefix` part of both of the following filenames?

- `xyz` can be any character of `[a-z0-9-_\ ]`
- `some.prefix` part can be any character in `[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.\ ]`.

I intentionally included a `.` in `some.prefix`.

```
some.prefix.xyz.xyz
some.prefix.xyz
```

I have tried many combinations. For example:

```
(?P<prefix>[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+)(?:\.[a-z0-9]+\.gz|\.[a-z0-9]+)
```

It works with `abc.def.csv` by catching `abc.def`, but fail to catch it in `abc.def.csv.gz`.

I primarily use Python, but I thought the regex itself should apply to many languages.

**Update**: It's not possible, see discussion with @nowox below.

Comment: Removing anything after last `.` will give filename. Replace `\.[^.]+$`.

Comment: I forgot to add that the prefix part can contain `\.`, too. Now added. I wonder if it's possible at all to get such a regex, vaguely remember regex is greedy in a way.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/checking-file-extension

Comment: @Robert, I understand it can be done with Python, but for this particular question, I need a regex string, it's used by some other Python function, so it's not really about Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your *regex* works pretty well. I recommend you to trying [regex101](https://regex101.com) with your example:

https://regex101.com/r/dV6cE8/3

The expression

```
^(?i)[ \w-]+\.[ \w-]+
```

Should work in your case:

```
som e.prefix.xyz.xyz
^^^^^^^^^^^
some.prefix.xyz
^^^^^^^^^^^
abc.def.csv.gz
^^^^^^^
```

And in Python you can use:

```
import re

text = """some.prefix.xyz.xyz
some.prefix.xyz
abc.def.csv.gz"""

print re.findall('^(?i)[ \w-]+\.[ \w-]+', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Which will display:

```
['som e.prefix', 'some.prefix', 'abc.def']
```

I might think you are a bit confused about your requirement. If I summarize, you have a pathname made of `chars` and `dot` such as:

```
foo.bar.baz.0
foobar.tar.gz
f.o.o.b.a.r
```

How would you separate these string into a base-name and an extension? Here we recognize some known patterns `.tar.gz` is definitely an extension, but is `.bar.baz.0` the extension or it is only `.0`?

The answer is not easy and no regexes in this World would be able to guess the correct answer at 100% without some hints.

For example you can list the acceptable extensions and make some criteria:

- An extension match the regex `\.\w{1,4}$`
- Several extensions may be concatenated together `(\.\w{1,4}){1,4}$`
- The remaining is called the `basename`

From this you can build this regular expression:

```
(?P<basename>.*?)(?P<extension>(?:\.\w{1,4}){1,4})$
```

Comment: In the first example, I would just like to want to `some.prefix`, no `xyz`. In the third example, only `abc.def`, no `csv`.

Comment: That seems to work. Is it possible to consider space, for example `some.pre fix.xyz.xyz`

Comment: I see, I wasn't being super clear in my question. What if the filename is `some.prefix.2.csv.gz`, can your regex match `some.other.prefix.2`? Similarly, there could be `some.prefix.2.3`, `some.prefix.2.3.4` etc. I only want the last one or two exts to be excluded after matching.

Comment: The main question is how to differentiate what belong to the file name and what belong to the extension. What do you want to keep in this example: `a.b.c.d.e.f.g`?

Comment: I see your point. So it's not possible to come up with such a question. Can you add this to your comment, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this`[a-z0-9-_\\]+\.[a-z0-9-_\\]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.\\]+`

Comment: It worked for me .. just to be clear you want both results to match?

Comment: I want it to be able to extract the `some.prefix` part of a filename. For example, if the filename is `abc.def.csv.gz`, it should be able to extract the `abc.def` from the matched results. You probably need some grouping in your regex string (e.g. with parenthesis)