# Check for valid file extension

Tags: validation, python-3.x

On user input I am trying to validate they typed an appropriate file extension. For example:

```
file1 = input('Enter the file name ending in ".txt": ')
```

I'd like to validate that they entered '.txt'. Right now I'm doing very basic checking. However, the check below doesn't really validate that the file 'ends' in .txt.

```
if '.txt' not in file_name:
    print('Include file extension (example): ".txt"')
```

So I suppose its validating only 'txt' characters exist after '.' but only if that is the final '.', for example, I wouldn't want it to accidentally catch on "dinosoars" in baby.dinosoars.txt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/checking-file-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your filename into a string `s`, you can use endswith:

```
if s.endswith('.txt'):
...
elif s.endswith('.test'):
...
```

Or the case-insensitive version (and eliminate any else-if chain)

```
s.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `endswith` instead?

```
if not file_name.endswith(extension):
    #exec code
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
    print "something"
```

Comment: `endswith` instead of `ends_with` and `print` needs parenthesis in Python 3.x