# How to shorten multiple IF .... IN ... OR statements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, if-statement

How can I shorten the following MWE?

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg', 'c.png', 'd.JPG', 'e.JPG']
images = [x for x in files if '.jpg' in x or '.png' in x or '.JPG' in x]
print images
```

I was thinking in terms of

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg', 'c.png', 'd.JPG', 'e.JPG']
images = [x for x in files if ('.jpg' or '.png' or '.JPG') in x]
print images
```

which does not work.

In contrast to this post: [Checking file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/checking-file-extension), I am also interested in a generalization, which does not focus on the file ending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bit shorter

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg', 'c.png', 'd.JPG', 'e.JPG']
images = [x for x in files if x.endswith(('.jpg','.png','.JPG'))]
print images
```

It works because `endswith()` can take a tuple for input as you can see [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

You can even do this to make it case insensitive

```
images = [x for x in files if x.lower().endswith(('.jpg','.png'))]
```

Comment: This works great for my MWE, many thanks. As an extension, could endswith() be replaced by something like ''contains()'' and hence be more generally applied to cases that do not focus on the ending?

Comment: @CFW python has no contains but it has a `in` keyword. In that case it would be something like `[x for x in files if any(y in x for y in ('.jpg','.png','.JPG'))]` This will also match for example `'abc.pngabc'`

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg', 'c.png', 'd.JPG', 'e.JPG']
formats = ('.jpg', '.png', '.JPG')

# this gets you the images
images = [file for file in files if any (format in file for format in formats))

# The above is equivalent to the following statement which is longer 
# and looks complicated but probably easy to understand for someone new to [python list comprehension][1]
images = [file for file in files if any (format for format in formats if format in file))
```

but, but, having said that you should really use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260050/1920968) if you want to check for `.endswith`. I merely extended your premise (based on your question, which used `in`).

Recommended reading on list comprehension: [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Why not `any(format in file for format in formats)`?

Comment: sure, it's an quivalent @tobias_k.

Comment: @zEro: It is better to just keep the edited answer and remove the one you stated earlier. Also, you may remove the name of tobias_k from the answer, he won't mind ;)

Comment: I kept the original, so the OP may compare and understand what we did there.

Comment: In that case, it is better to flip the answers. Focus should be on the efficient way to achieve the outcome. Because SO is not for just the OP; other people will also refer it in the future :)

Comment: That's fair, @MoinuddinQuadri. Updating.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
import os

files = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg', 'c.png', 'd.JPG', 'e.JPG']
images = [x for x in files if os.path.splitext(x)[-1] in   ['.jpg','.png','.JPG']]
print images
```