# Can't get file extension of temp image file grabbed using Image.open(requests.get())

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library, google-places-api

This is the first question I've asked on here so excuse any inexperience :-)

I have the following file for saving images and then returning me the file path/URL:

```
import os, requests
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import url_for, current_app

def save_picture(google_url):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    i = Image.open(requests.get(google_url, stream=True).raw)
    f_ext = (i.format).lower()
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/experience_images', picture_fn)

    output_size = (600, 600)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.show()
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn
```

I am getting the following error

raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext))

The `google_url` parameter is a api URL to get an image from Google Places API. Below when I call `i.show()` the image opens up so I know the image is coming through, and I can see that in most cases (though not necessarily all) it is returning a PNG or JPEG file. I think the issue is that I'm not actually getting any filename from `i`, and I am assuming this is because it's a tempfile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm a bit of a newbie to Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the extension of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/how-can-i-check-the-extension-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, because I don't a Google Places account, however: generally, HTTP responses will declare the type of data that they contain in the content type header.

The header's value might look like this

```
"image/jpeg"
```

or this

```
"image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8"
```

The [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) module in the standard library contains tools to derive the extenstion from this header value.  So you could do something like this:

```
import mimetypes
import requests

def save_picture(google_url):

    response = requests.get(google_url, stream=True)
    content_type = response.headers['content-type']    # 'image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8'
    mimetype, _, _ = content_type.partition(';')       # 'image/jpeg'
    f_ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(mimetype)        # '.jpg'

    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    i = Image.open(response.raw)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/experience_images', picture_fn)

    output_size = (600, 600)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.show()
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the PIL [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) the format string may be None under certain circumstances. (It would be helpful if you would post a complete example that I can run in a notebook and play with, if I use a random image URL it basically works.)

It might be enough to provide a default format (.jpg?)
    f_ext = (i.format).lower() if i.format is not None else '.jpg'
for those cases, but guessing a bit here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have figured out a solution. If others have a better solution I am all ears.

Basically what seems to have been the problem is when I get the file extension type using `i.format` it doesn't include the '.' in '.PNG'. So The filename was something like 'filenamepng' instead of 'filename.png'.

So now after getting the file extension with

```
f_ext = i.format
```

I create the filename with

```
picture_fn = random_hex + '.' + f_ext
```

Now everything seems to work :-) Thanks to DrD, I figured this out while putting together a sample code snippet for you to try out.

The completed code now is as follows:

```
import os, requests
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import url_for, current_app

def save_picture(google_url):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    i = Image.open(requests.get(google_url, stream=True).raw)
    f_ext = (i.format).lower()
    picture_fn = random_hex + '.' + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/experience_images', picture_fn)

    output_size = (600, 600)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn
```