# How to find the real file extension of a file with python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file `test.pdf` but I changed the extension to `jpeg` such that the file is now `test.jpeg`. The actual file format should still be a pdf file as the file signature for a pdf is `25 50 44 46 2d` and the file signature for a jpeg is either `FF D8 FF DB` or `FF D8 FF EE` and a couple other ones.

I tried it with a few suggestions from [How can I check the extension of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/how-can-i-check-the-extension-of-a-file). But they all appear to just be finding what the `apparent file extension` is. For example,

```
>>> file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext("/Users/mark/Desktop/test.jpeg")
>>> file_extension
'.jpeg'
>>>
```

As shown the file extension provided in the end is `.jpeg` but the real file extension is actually still `.pdf`.

Comment: The "real" file extension of a file called `test.jpeg` is `.jpeg`. Whatever the file's actual contents, the *file extension* is just the last part of the filename.

Comment: you need to open the file and try to guess, using fourcc, magic number, whatever

Comment: @khelwood, not true, if there is a forum that allows an upload of images and someone writes a malware in python and changes the file extension to a jpeg and successfully uploads it, that's a problem

Comment: @Mark That is irrelevant to my statement. I'm not saying the contents of the file are not important. I'm saying your question suggests a misunderstanding of what "file extension" means.

Comment: Mark, what @khelwood is trying to say is that the extension is inherently part of the filename. What you should be asking is what is the file type.

Comment: If you are using Linux, there is a system command call "file" that will make a pretty good guess at this for you.  You would, of course, have to fork a process and examine the stdout.  If you are using Windows, the GNUWIN32 toolset has a copy of the "file" command in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who also has the same problem as me, the following worked for me. I had to install `magic` from https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic first.

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file("/Users/mark/Desktop/test_copy.jpeg")
'HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines'
```