# Getting file extension using pattern matching in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the extension of a file, given its name as a string. I know I can use the function `os.path.splitext` but it does not work as expected in case my file extension is `.tar.gz` or `.tar.bz2` as it gives the extensions as `gz` and `bz2` instead of `tar.gz` and `tar.bz2` respectively.
So I decided to find the extension of files myself using pattern matching.

```
print re.compile(r'^.*[.](?P<ext>tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|\w+)$').match('a.tar.gz')group('ext')
>>> gz            # I want this to come as 'tar.gz'
print re.compile(r'^.*[.](?P<ext>tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|\w+)$').match('a.tar.bz2')group('ext')
>>> bz2           # I want this to come 'tar.bz2'
```

I am using `(?P<ext>...)` in my pattern matching as I also want to get the extension.

Please help.

Comment: What if name="hi.c.java" in case you want .java alone right ?

Comment: for the time being, yes. But, I should be able to add more in the regex pattern later if I want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print re.compile(r'^.*[.](?P<ext>tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|\w+)$').match('a.tar.gz').group('ext')
gz
>>> print re.compile(r'^.*?[.](?P<ext>tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|\w+)$').match('a.tar.gz').group('ext')
tar.gz
>>>
```

The ? operator tries to find the minimal match, so instead of .* eating ".tar" as well, .*? finds the minimal match that allows .tar.gz to be matched.

Comment: I really thank you for this! This thing took a lot of my time!

Answer (score 21):

```
root,ext = os.path.splitext('a.tar.gz')
if ext in ['.gz', '.bz2']:
   ext = os.path.splitext(root)[1] + ext
```

<sub>Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.</sub>

Comment: Ok that will work in this case but I want to solve it using python regular expressions.

Comment: @Guanidene: If it's homework, mark the question homework.  If it's not homework, don't use a regular expression when the function's already been written, debugged and works.

Comment: @S.Lott - It is no homework, I want to tackle the problem using regex thats all. If just solving was the aim, I could have done it long before as phihag says.

Comment: @phihag - one more reason why I wish to use regex - It is compact. If I go your way, I will unnecessarily need 3 lines (and which also makes my code clumsy), while using regex I can get everything in a single line!

Comment: @Guanidene More compact does not equal more readable and maintainable. Also, why is a complicated regular expression less clumsy than three lines even non-programmers could understand? Anyway, to each his own.

Answer (score 3):

I have idea which is much easier than breaking your head with regex,sometime it might sound stupid too.

`name="filename.tar.gz"

extensions=('.tar.gz','.py')

[x for x in extensions if name.endswith(x)]`

Comment: Suppose there exists a file extension `.gz` (assume) too which I may want to match. So in this case your tuple will be `extensions=('.gz','.tar.gz','.py')` (and name=`filenmae.tar.gz`) and if I execute this  - `[x for x in extensions if name.endswith(x)]` it will wrongly match `gz` when I want to match it with `tar.gz`.
Dude, what I want is a universal solution, not a data specific solution!

Comment: There is a option for that ,so place tar.gz first in the list if it matches return,but this method will not work once you place gz before tar.gz.>>> extensions=('tar.gz','gz','py')
`>>> name
'set.tar.gz'
>>> def test():
...     for x in extensions:
...             if name.endswith(x):
...                     return x
...    return ' '
>>> test()
'tar.gz'
>>> 
`

Comment: @Guanidene:Yea I will not remember agreed,but you can leave a comment,might be regex is a correct solution and it is,but while answering the question I started by saying it might be stupid and there is a option,I am not arguing this is right .

Answer (score 3):

Starting from phihags answer:

```
DOUBLE_EXTENSIONS = ['tar.gz','tar.bz2'] # Add extra extensions where desired.

def guess_extension(filename):
    """
    Guess the extension of given filename.
    """
    root,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in DOUBLE_EXTENSIONS]):
        root, first_ext = os.path.splitext(root)
        ext = first_ext + ext
    return root, ext
```

Answer (score 2):

this is simple and works on both single and multiple extensions

```
In [1]: '/folder/folder/folder/filename.tar.gz'.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
Out[1]: 'filename'

In [2]: '/folder/folder/folder/filename.tar'.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
Out[2]: 'filename'

In [3]: 'filename.tar.gz'.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
Out[3]: 'filename'
```

Comment: In [4]:  '/folder/folder/folder/filename.tar.gz'.split('/')[-1].split('.')[1:]
Out[4]: ['tar', 'gz']

Works well for me!

Comment: A variant I used of this to get the filename and file extension:
`f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(body).split("/")[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from phihags answer to generic remove all double or triple extensions such as CropQDS275.jpg.aux.xml use while '.' in:

```
tempfilename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
while '.' in tempfilename:
     tempfilename, tempfile_extension = os.path.splitext(tempfilename)
     file_extension = tempfile_extension + file_extension
```