# How to cut tar.gz extension from filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with deleting extension from my filename. I tried to use

```
os.path.splitext(checked_delivery)[0]
```

, but it delete only `.gz` from filename. I need to check if file has extension or it's a directory. I did it using this:

```
os.path.exists(delivery)
```

But another problem is, that I can't split it cause of data in it (YYYY.MM.DD). Should I use `join()` or it is something more attractive instead of tons of methods and ifs?

Comment: Are you checking if it's a directory?

Comment: it could be a tar.gz file or already unpacked directory

Comment: Possible duplication for [What's the way to extract file extension from file name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976192/whats-the-way-to-extract-file-extension-from-file-name-in-python)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you know that the extension is *always* going to be .tar.gz, you can still use split:

```
In [1]: fname = 'RANDOM_FILE-2017.06.07.tar.gz'

In [2]: '.'.join(fname.split('.')[:-2])
Out[2]: 'RANDOM_FILE-2017.06.07'
```

From the docstring for os.path.splitext:

```
"Extension is everything from the last dot to the end, ignoring leading dots. "
```

In the case of gzipped tarballs, this makes sense anyway, as the file 'FILE.tar.gz' is a gzipped version of the 'FILE.tar', which is presumably a tarball made from file 'FILE'

This is why you would need to use something other than os.path.splitext for this, if what you need is the original filename, without .tar

Comment: So check if it's a dir and if not -> your second line. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, `os.path.isdir(...)`, then use the above from my answer for removing the extension.

Comment: why not `fname.replace(".tar.gz")` ? unlikely to be in the middle of a name, and that doesn't kill other dots in filenames like YYYY.MM.DD if it's a dir

Comment: just in case if any whats to do it in *nix
`basename -s .tar.gz filename.tar.gz`

Comment: If you know the extension is _always_ going to be '.tar.gz' you can just slice without the last `len('.tar.gz')` characters.  Maybe checking with `endswith()` if the assumption is right, before slicing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, only `fname,replace(".tar.gz", "")` works. Replace method: `str.replace(old, new[, max])`

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following small function:

```py
def strip_extension(fn: str, extensions=[".tar.bz2", ".tar.gz"]):
    for ext in extensions:
        if fn.endswith(ext):
            return fn[: -len(ext)]
    raise ValueError(f"Unexpected extension for filename: {fn}")

assert strip_extension("foo.tar.gz") == "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a generic solution to remove the file extension from the string using the `pathlib` module. Using the `os` to manage the paths is not that convenient nowadays, IMO.

```
import pathlib


def remove_extention(path: pathlib.PosixPath) -> path.PosixPath:
    suffixes = ''.join(path.suffixes)
    return pathlib.Path(str(path).replace(suffixes, ''))
```