# Extract document extensions from clicks

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics, sharepoint-2013

I'm using [this technique](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics-v2) to extract the click events in my SharePoint site. It uses jquery and a regular expression to capture clicks and report them as events to google analytics.

I'm also just past total newbie with regex -- It is starting to make some sense to me, but I have a lot to learn still. So here goes.

I have a preapproved list of filetypes that I am interested in based on the site listed above.

```
var filetypes = /\.(zip|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav|jpg)$/i;
```

But it isn't quite working like I need. With the **$** I assume it is trying to match to the end of the line. But often in SharePoint we get links like this:

> example.org/sharepoint/_layouts/15/wopiframe.aspx?sourcedoc=/sharepointlibrary/**the%20document%20name.docx**&action=default&defaultitemopen=1

The two problems I have are, I can't count on the file name being before the query or hash and I can't count on it being at the end. And all the different Microsoft Office extensions.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582171/javascript-regex-for-matching-extracting-file-extension) on extracting extensions, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

I've put together this version

```
var filetypes = \.(zip|pdf|doc|xls|ppt|mp3|txt|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav|jpg)[A-Za-z]*
```

I changed the office bits from **doc.*** to just plain **doc** and added the optional alpha character afterwards. And removed the $ end anchor. It seems to be working with my test sample, but I don't know if there are gotchas that I don't understand.

Does this seem like a good solution or is there a better way to get a predetermined list of extensions (including for example the Office varions like doc, docx, docm) that is either before the query string or might be one parameter in the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the following which matches file name and extension:

```
/[^/]+\.(zip|pdf|doc[xm]?|xlsx?|ppt|mp3|txt|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav|jpg)/i
```

Outputs `the%20document%20name.docx` from you example.

There may be other formats that it might not work on but should get you what you want.

Comment: That is awesome. At the moment I don't need to get the The actual name of the document — just the extension — but thanks for adding that in. The file name might not always start after / so **[^/?&]+** might work better.