# Extract file extension from Pyspark Dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column `FullPath`.

How can I use the function `os.path.splitext(FullPath)` to extract the extension of each entry in the `FullPath` column and put them in a new column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) to [extract the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582171/javascript-regex-for-matching-extracting-file-extension):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('/tmp/filename.tar.gz',)
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["FullPath"])
df.withColumn("extension", f.regexp_extract("FullPath", "\.[0-9a-z]+$", 0)).show()
#+--------------------+---------+
#|            FullPath|extension|
#+--------------------+---------+
#|/tmp/filename.tar.gz|      .gz|
#+--------------------+---------+
```

However if you wanted to use `os.path.splittext()`, you would need to use a `udf` (which will be slower than the above alternative):

```python
import os
splittext = f.udf(lambda FullPath: os.path.splitext(FullPath)[-1], StringType())
df.withColumn("extension", splittext("FullPath")).show()
#+--------------------+---------+
#|            FullPath|extension|
#+--------------------+---------+
#|/tmp/filename.tar.gz|      .gz|
#+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a split function the SQL functions module, so you can split your full path on the "." character and take the last element. Assuming that there is only one "." in each filepath string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("pathArray", F.split(myDataFrame.FullPath, ".")
myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("FileExtension", myDataFrame.pathArray.getItem(1))
```

Comment: The file may have more than one dot like /tmp/filename.tar.gz for example.