# JavaScript RegExp to recognize specific file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way how to write a JavaScript regular expression that would recognize **.ts** file extension for this:

```
"file.ts"
```

but would fail on this:

```
"file.vue.ts"
```

What I need is, if the file name ends with **.vue.ts**, it shouldn't be handled as a **.ts** file.

I've tried a lot of things with no success.

Update: It needs to be a regular expression, because that's what I'm passing to a parameter of a function.

Comment: has it to be a regular expression?

Comment: /(.*).ts$/   this should check that the last 3 chars are '.ts'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex JavaScript image file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473185/regex-javascript-image-file-extension)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regex for matching/extracting file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582171/javascript-regex-for-matching-extracting-file-extension)

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, I need it to be a regular expression.

Comment: how do you know, that `.vue.ts` is another file extension and not another name with a dot?

Comment: @NinaScholz Because that's how the system works.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I have tried searching for the solution for several hours, that's why I'm here. If you could provide the answer or a link from Google, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex for that is `^[^.]+.ts$`

```js
var x=/^[^.]+.ts$/;
console.log(x.test("file.ts"));
console.log(x.test("file.vue.ts"));
console.log(x.test("file.vue.ts1"));
```

Explanation:-

```
^[^.]+.ts$

^        ---> start of line
[^.]+    ---> match anything which is not '.' (match atleast one character)
^[^.]+   ---> match character until first '.' encounter
.ts      ---> match '.ts'
$        ---> end of line
.ts$     ---> string end with '.ts'
```

Comment: I need it not to match for "file.vue.ts". Your expression results in a match in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could look for a previous coming dot and if not return `true`.

```js
console.log(["file.ts", "file.vue.ts"].map(s => /^[^.]+\.ts$/.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work except for special characters. Will allow for uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+(\.ts)$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const regex = /(.*[^.vue]).ts/g;
abc.ts.ts Matches
abc.xyx.htm.ts Matches
abc.vue.ts Fails
xyz.abx.sxc.vue.ts Fails
```

Javascript regex should be this one.

Comment: "file.ts" won't pass, because of "e" in "file", I guess.