# Execute process from the windows command line in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

I would like to know how to execute this java process using the windows command line, from inside Python 2.7 on Windows 8.

I thought I had already solved this problem, but I recently changed computers from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and my code stopped working.  I have confirmed that the windows command used in the script below executes properly when run directly from cmd.exe

```
import os
import subprocess

def FileProcess(inFile):
    #Create the startup info so the java program runs in the background (for windows computers)
    startupinfo = None
    if os.name == 'nt':
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    #Execute Stanford Core NLP from the command line
    print inFile
    cmd = ['java', '-Xmx1g','-cp', 'stanford-corenlp-1.3.5.jar;stanford-corenlp-1.3.5-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP', '-annotators', 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse', '-file', inFile]
    output = subprocess.call(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo)
    print inFile[(str(inFile).rfind('\\'))+1:] + '.xml'
    outFile = file(inFile[(str(inFile).rfind('\\'))+1:] + '.xml')

FileProcess("C:\\NSF_Stuff\\ErrorPropagationPaper\\RandomTuftsPlain\\PreprocessedTufts8199PLAIN.txt")
```

When this code is executed, I receive the error message that the output file does not exist.  The java process I am executing should output an xml file when it is done.

It is my belief that for some reason subprocess.call is never successfully executing the command. I have tried using subprocesss.popen for the same task and I get the same results.

EDIT: I have changed my code so that I can capture error messages and I think I am beginning to understand the problem.

I changed my code to

```
import os
import subprocess

def FileProcess(inFile):
    #Create the startup info so the java program runs in the background (for windows computers)
    startupinfo = None
    if os.name == 'nt':
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    #Execute Stanford Core NLP from the command line
    print inFile
    cmd = ['java', '-Xmx1g','-cp', 'stanford-corenlp-1.3.5.jar;stanford-corenlp-1.3.5-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP', '-annotators', 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse', '-file', inFile]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    print proc
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate()
    print stdoutdata
    print stderrdata
    outFile = file(inFile[(str(inFile).rfind('\\'))+1:] + '.xml')

FileProcess("C:\\NSF_Stuff\\ErrorPropagationPaper\\RandomTuftsPlain\\PreprocessedTufts8199PLAIN.txt")
```

stdoutdata contains the message "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Now this is a very bizarre message because java is definitely a recognized command when I run it from the cmd.exe .  There is some issue here where executing the command from python is messing with my system environment variables such that java is no longer recognized as a command.

Comment: could you plese show us your inFile value you use?

Comment: It is provided in the code.  It is just the absolute path of a .txt file.

Comment: try to print out your cmd variable like this: `print " ".join(cmd)` and then try to run it from cmd.exe

Comment: That print statement yields: "java -Xmx1g -cp stanford-corenlp-1.3.5.jar;stanford-corenlp-1.3.5-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse -file C:\NSF_Stuff\ErrorPropagationPaper\RandomTuftsPlain\PreprocessedTufts8199PLAIN.txt" which produces correct output from the command line when I run it from the same location the python script is executing from.

Comment: what IDE do you use? how do you run your script? it maybe just the current working directory issue. I've edited the code.

Comment: try to run `print os.environ['PATH']` in your script and check if you have java in it

Comment: Thanks nio! I did this and it led me to the correct answer.  Apparently java wasn't in my path variable.  I didn't even bother checking this originally because I was having no problems executing java commands from the windows command line.  I'm guessing that commands executed directly from cmd.exe use a different path variable than one's executed using the subprocess module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by adding the location of java to my PATH variable. Apparently java wasn't in my path variable. I didn't even bother checking this originally because I was having no problems executing java commands from the windows command line. I'm guessing that commands executed directly from cmd.exe use a different environment variable to find the java executable than commands executed indirectly from the subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

By trying your code it prints out `PreprocessedTufts8199PLAIN.txt.xml` file name. I'm not sure if the `.txt.xml` extension was the desired result. If your file has only `.xml` extension, then you're not stripping away the original `.txt` header.

Try to change this line:

```
outFile = file(inFile[(str(inFile).rfind('\\'))+1:] + '.xml')
```

Into this code:

```
fnameext = inFile[(str(inFile).rfind('\\'))+1:]
fname,fext = os.path.splitext(fnameext)
xmlfname = fname + '.xml'
xmlfpath =  os.path.join(".", xmlfname)
print "xmlfname:", xmlfname, " xmlfpath:", xmlfpath
print "current working directory:", os.getcwd()
outFile = open(xmlfpath, "r")
```

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python) for extension stripping.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem lies somewhere before this issue because the xml file is never being created at all at this point.