# How to get file extension correctly?

Tags: python

I know that this question is asked many times on this website. But I found that they missed an important point: only file extension with one period was taken into consider like `*.png *.mp3`, but how do I deal with these filename with two period like `.tar.gz`.

The basic code is:

```
filename = '/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt'
extention = filename.split('/')[-1]
```

But obviously, this code do not work with the file like `a.tar.gz`.
How to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: By the way in your code, the variable `extension` is actually storing the complete filename, it does the same thing regardless of the type of extension.

Comment: your code is a wrong example: it's giving you the " basename " of the path, not the extension, which is equivalent to `import os;os.path.basename('/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt')`

Comment: a.tar.gz is a "gzip-compressed" tar file. So the extension of this file is  `gz` and not `tar.gz`. So this question comes down to finding substrings ".tar.gz" etc, in the file names. If you see Rahul's edit, you will find that this is true.

Comment: Hey guys, I found an more interesting thing that if I compress `a.ppt` the default filename will be `a.ppt.tar.gz`, so there will be more disturbances. Please take this into consider.

Comment: @SilentMonk But if I rename `a.tar.gz` to `a.tar(2).gz`, I cannot open it properly, so the extension is `tar.gz`.

Comment: You can open `a.tar(2).gz` just fine: `gunzip` will work fine on that file.

Comment: @Evert But I got  `unknown suffix -- ignored` from
`gunzip a.ppt.tar\(2\)`. What goes wrong?

Comment: Obviusly, you should *not* run `gunzip` on `a.ppt.tar\(2\)`, but on `a.ppt.tar\(2\).gz`...

Comment: @Evert sorry, misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting extension from filename in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: @Rahul 's answer is the better way. i.e using `os.path.splitext('/path/to/your/file')` If you need a one line code you can use something like `(os.path.splitext('path/to/file.ext')[1]).split('.')[1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The role of a file extension is to tell the viewer (and sometimes the computer) which application to use to handle the file.

Taking your worst-case example in your comments (`a.ppt.tar.gz`), this is a PowerPoint file that has been tar-balled and then gzipped. So you need to use a gzip-handling program to open it. Using PowerPoint or a tarball-handling program wouldn't work. OK, a clever program that knew how to handle both `.tar` and `.gz` files could understand both operations and work with a `.tar.gz` file - but note that it would do that *even if the extension was simply `.gz`*.

The fact that both `tar` and `gzip` add their extensions to the original filename, rather than replace them (as `zip` does) is a convenience. But the base name of the gzip file is still `a.ppt.tar`.

Comment: @David, this is what I tried to convey in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your explain, based on this idea, I think @no11 's code is simple and good enough for me, but I still think you have got the best answer.

Comment: @Rahul 's answer is the better way. i.e using `os.path.splitext('/path/to/your/file')` If you need a one line code you can use something like `(os.path.splitext('path/to/file.ext')[1]).split('.')[1]`

Answer (score 106):

## **Python 3.4**

You can now use [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from pathlib. It has many features, one of them is [`suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('my/library/setup.py').suffix
'.py'
>>> Path('my/library.tar.gz').suffix
'.gz'
>>> Path('my/library').suffix
''
```

If you want to get more than one suffix, use `suffixes`:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('my/library.tar.gar').suffixes
['.tar', '.gar']
>>> Path('my/library.tar.gz').suffixes
['.tar', '.gz']
>>> Path('my/library').suffixes
[]
```

Comment: Something that frustrated me: I googled for `Path` from pathlib documentation, and it told me to use .ext .  This kept failing and eventually I learned of .suffix.  Not sure if the first documentation was for an older version of the Path() library?

Comment: @Starman `pathlib` introduced in Python 3.4, make sure you're not looking at Python 2 docs.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a in build module in `os`. More about [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

```
In [1]: from os.path import splitext
In [2]: file_name,extension = splitext('/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt')
In [3]: extension
Out[1]: '.ppt'
```

If you have to fine the extension of `.tar.gz`,`.tar.bz2` you have to write a function like this

```
from os.path import splitext
def splitext_(path):
    for ext in ['.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2']:
        if path.endswith(ext):
            return path[:-len(ext)], path[-len(ext):]
    return splitext(path)
```

**Result**

```
In [4]: file_name,ext = splitext_('/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.tar.gz')
In [5]: ext
Out[2]: '.tar.gz'
```

**Edit**

Generally you can use this function

```
from os.path import splitext
def splitext_(path):
    if len(path.split('.')) > 2:
        return path.split('.')[0],'.'.join(path.split('.')[-2:])
    return splitext(path)
```

It will work for all extensions.

**Working on all files**.

```
In [6]: inputs = ['a.tar.gz', 'b.tar.lzma', 'a.tar.lz', 'a.tar.lzo', 'a.tar.xz','a.png']
In [7]: for file_ in inputs:                                                                    
    file_name,extension = splitext_(file_)
    print extension
   ....:     
tar.gz
tar.lzma
tar.lz
tar.lzo
tar.xz
.png
```

Comment: I tried it ,this not work for `/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.tar.gz`

Comment: So I need to write `['tar.gz', 'tar.lzma', 'tar.lz', 'tar.lzo', 'tar.xz', etc...]` into my code? There must be many extension like this.

Comment: @DavidPage Updated my answer again.

Comment: I think @no11 's solution is better because you used more `split` then him, and his code works well.

Comment: @DavidPage I tried to get the file name as well as the extension. It's a part of the coordination of in build function of `splitext`. That's why there is more  occurrence of `split`

Comment: I think change the fourth line to `return '.'.join(path.split('.')[:-2]),'.'.join(path.split('.')[-2:])` will be better for `a.ppt.tar.gz`.

Comment: I think the extension of `a.tar.gz` file is .gz :) not `.tar.gz` isn't it? so `os.path.splitext()` gives right result. :)

Comment: @Tharanga Solution according the OP's requirement. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Simplest One:**

```
import os.path
print os.path.splitext("/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt")[1]
# '.ppt'
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is:

1. Slice at "." => `tmp_ext = filename.split('.')[1:]`

Result is a list = `['tar', 'gz']`

2. Join them together => `extention = ".".join(tmp_ext)`

Result is your extension as string = `'tar.gz'`

Update: Example:

```
>>> test = "/test/test/test.tar.gz"
>>> t2 = test.split(".")[1:]
>>> t2
['tar', 'gz']
>>> ".".join(t2)
'tar.gz'
```

Comment: this will crash for filenames without a dot but except for that it will give what the OP asked for

Comment: Ok. But for that case he already has a solution. So the core-question would be solved with my solution. But okay...

Comment: Although I found this solution pretty smart, it does not work for some cases. For example, some users put dots in the file name: 'my_document_on11.11.2019.docx'.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> import re

>>> filename = os.path.basename('/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt')  
>>> extensions = re.findall(r'\.([^.]+)', basename)
['ppt']


>>> filename = os.path.basename('/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.ppt.tar.gz')  
>>> extensions = re.findall(r'\.([^.]+)', basename)
['ppt','tar','gz']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with re.findall and python 3.6

filename = '/home/Downloads/abc.ppt.tar.gz'

ext = r'\.\w{1,6}'

re.findall(f'{ext}\\b | {ext}$', filename,  re.X)

['.ppt', '.tar', '.gz']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
filename = '/home/lancaster/Downloads/a.tar.gz'
extention = filename.split('/')[-1]

if '.' in extention:
  extention = extention.split('.')[-1]
  if len(extention) > 0:
    extention = '.'+extention
    print extention
```

Comment: what's problem in this?