# Convert a list with filenames in to a name and suffix list in Python

Tags: python

i have a list with filenames. How do i use the `os.path.splitext()` function to split the suffix and a filename and wirte it again into a list without the  suffix.

```
import os
image_names = os.listdir('C:\Pictures\Sample Pictures')
newimageList = []
for name in image_names:
  newimageList.append(name.os.path.splitext())
print(newList)
```

unfortunately the code don't work i get an Error: `'str' object has no attribute 'os'`

if i had a new list(separeted in filename and suffix) i would skip every second element in a list to get just the filenames

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), you should try `os.path.splitext('/desired_path')`.

You just have to adjust your code...

So, instead of:

```
newimageList.append(name.os.path.splitext())
```

Use:

```
newimageList.append(os.path.splitext(name))
```

Comment: Correct, but it is not 'according to the docs', it is more of a python grammar issue: It is not `x.a.b()` but instead `a.b(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You want `os.path.splitext(name)` instead of `name.os.path.splitext()`.