# python get extension file: splitext vs endswith

Tags: python

I'm wondering which is the better way of these two ones to get the file extension, and check if it belongs to a list.

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
return ext == ".pdf" # an example
```

or

```
return filename.endswith(".pdf")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting extension from filename in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: @vabada Just the subject. The actual question isn't about getting the extension but comparing/checking it against a given extension value.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two examples of checking with both methods if a filename contains any of the extensions.

```
ext = ('.txt', '.py', '.docx', '.pdf') # tuple of extensions.

filenames = [ ... ] # list of filename strings
ends_matches = [ f for f in filenames if f.endswith(ext) ]

# change ext to set for slightly better efficiency.
split_matches = [ f for f in filenames if f.splitext()[1] in ext ]

# may need to include .lower() for cases with capital extensions.
```

In this case it is really up to you which you want to use. If you just want to check a single file extension then I would suggest with the latter, `endswith`.

```
return filename.endswith(extension)
```

Answer (score 1):

Second one is cleaner and shorter solution I would say if you need to only check for specific extension. Both work even on special cases like filename = `abc.def.pdf`.

First one is better if you need to process somehow filename and/or extension later.

Answer (score 1):

`endswith()` is commonly used to check for file names. A pythonic approach to filter out certain file extensions in a list of file names could be done as follows:

```
>>> extensions = ('.pdf', '.txt', '.rtf')
>>> [file_name for file_name in files if file_name.lower().endswith(extensions)]
# Output -> File names that end with any of those extensions.
```

With this sort of approach you can provide many file extensions in a tuple, and potentially eliminating an `if/else` ladder (*clean code :D*).