# How to copy file with a different name, but same extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I would like to copy a file, but I want the new file to be named something different, like having a (1) next to the name without changing the extension.

Here is my code:

```
import shutil
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os


filename = askopenfilename()

file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

dec = "_dec"

newfile = file_name + dec


copied = str.join(newfile, file_extension)


shutil.copy(filename, copied )

master = Tk()

w = Message(master, text="Copied!", width = 100)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

How would I get filename to have a (1) at the end of the name without touching the extension?

Comment: change the destination (the second parameter to `shutil.copy`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python/

Comment: What type is ```filename```? Is it a string? In which case, you can split on the ```.``` and change the first part, then ```join()``` again.

Comment: I know that, but if I do like +  "(1)" the (1) comes after the extension name. It would be like hi.txt(1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to get the root and extension. Then you can increment the filename with a number until it does not exist, add the extension back, and save the file.