# How to get a list of filenames(without extension) in directory in python?

Tags: python

Assume my folder structure to be

```
+Data
  -abc.jpg
  -db.jpg
  -ap.jpg
```

Input is 'path/to/Data'

Expected output is ['abc','db','ap']

I saw many similar questions but did not get what exactly I wanted.
I prefer to use os module in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: For extracting the file name have a look here: [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: Have a look at os.walk()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import os    
files_no_ext = [".".join(f.split(".")[:-1]) for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]
print(files_no_ext)
```

Comment: [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.listdir) does not make a difference between directories and files, so your list will have (mostly empty) entries for subdirectories.

Comment: You could furthermore exchange your `join/split` by [`os.path.splitext(f)[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), which takes care of some special cases (leading periods on the basename).

Answer (score 14):

simply try this,

```
l=os.listdir('path')
li=[x.split('.')[0] for x in l]
```

1. First list your directory files
2. split file by`.` and take first argument.

Comment: What happens if the name of the file itself contains a period? (macOS does allow this.) Is there a way to make sure the file is split using the last period?

Comment: Yeah, you can, remove last word after split then perform merge of rest of the values.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

for f in glob.glob("*.*"):
    print(Path(f).stem)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a top-up on the answer, it is supposed `import pathlib`, then `pathlib.Path(f).stem`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
filenames=next(os.walk(os.getcwd()))[2]
efn=[f.split('.')[0] for f in filenames]

os.getcwd()   #for get current directory path
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) which take path as argument and return a list of files **and** directories in it.
`>>> list_ = os.listdir("path/to/Data")`
`>>> list_`
`>>> ['abc.jpg', 'dn.jpg', 'ap.jpg']`

With that list, you only have to do a comprehension list which split each element on '.' (dot), take all the elements except the last one an join them with '.' (dot) and check if the element is a file using [os.path.file()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).

`>>> list_ = ['.'.join(x.split('.')[:-1]) for x in os.listdir("path/to/Data") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('path/to/Data', x))]`
`>>> list_`
`>>> ['abc', 'dn', 'ap']`

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    def filesMinusExtension(path):
        # os.path.splitext(f)[0] map with filename without extension with checking if file exists.
        files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))];
        return files;
```

Comment: There are some problems with you code...  
But, what bother me is : semi-colons ?  You are in Python guy, just throw them away !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes the java background seems to affect my python typing of semicolons at times. Anyway can you share what problems could arise with this code ?

Comment: Except semi-colons, why importing isfile and join that way without doing it for os.path.splittext ?
Furthermore, you use a comprehension list for filtering (the 'if' at the right) but not for mapping.
You just have to do `[os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]`.

Comment: Okay I've done the research and you are right. My modified solution removed redundant and unnecessary code.

Comment: You can even not use an intermediate variable and directly return the comprehension list if you want.