# Pythonic way to create a list of strings from file names (without file extension) in folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, directory

I have a folder in my computer with many `.txt` files:

```
file_one.txt    --> location = r'C:\Users\User\data\file_one.txt'
file_two.txt    --> location = r'C:\Users\User\data\file_two.txt'
file_forty.txt  --> location = r'C:\Users\User\data\file_forty.txt'
```

How can I turn the name of the files (without the `.txt` part) into a list like this:

```
list_from_files = ['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_forty']
```

Comment: Target dupe only covers half the question.

Comment: `[os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0] for f in os.listdir('/path/to/location')]`

Comment: use `os.listdir()` and `split` the name of files

Comment: Other half of the question is answered by this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `pathlib`<sup>1</sup>. It has a dedicated [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) property which returns the filename without suffix:

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path('.')   # current directory, insert your directory here
[x.stem for x in p.glob('*.txt')]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
`pathlib` is part of the [standard library in Python 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) - but you can use third-party (backport-)packages, available on PyPI and conda, like [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) and [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/) if you have an older Python version.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this but I much prefer MSeifert's answer. I checked and pathlib seems available in Python 2.7 as well.

You can try something like this

```
import os
import glob
print([os.path.splitext(os.path.split(x)[-1])[0] for x in glob.glob("/path/to/dir/*.txt")])
```

It uses a list comprehension, which you can read about [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

In `glob()` you can add in the path to your directory of choice.

`os.path.split(x)[-1]` gets the file name without the path info

`os.path.splitext(...)[0]` is used to split the `filename.extension` into a tuple `(filename, extension), of which the first element is chosen to get just the filename.

Comment: By making use of `glob` he cannot run the program from any other location, He has to run from that specific directory. Its better to accept a path of dirrectory.

Comment: He can do `glob("/path/to/my/dir/*.txt")`... ah I get it, he will get the paths that he doesn;t want... correcting, thank you

Comment: Yes he can, but unnecessary whole file path get attached for every files, because of `glob`

Comment: Yes, there's a backport of `pathlib` in PyPI: [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/). But it's not part of the standard library. You probably have that package installed if it works on 2.7.

Comment: What do you mean with "pathlib seems available in Python 2.7 as well"?

Comment: MSeifert's answer says "You could use pathlib in python 3.4+". it is also available in Python 2.7, as he points out, as a backport. I took his statement to indicate it might not be something you could use if you weren't using Python 3.