# split filename on name and extenstion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this pattern:

```
dir1/dir2/.log.gz
dir1/dir2/a.log.gz
dir1/dir2/a.py
dir1/dir2/*.gzip.tar
```

I want to get filename or path and extension. e.g:

```
(name,extension)=(dir1/dir2/,.log.gz)
(name,extension)=(dir1/dir2/a,.log.gz)
(name,extension)=(dir1/dir2/a,.py)
(name,extension)=(dir1/dir2/,.gzip.tar)
```

I try:

```
re.findall(r'(.*).*\.?(.*)',path)
```

but it doesn't work perfect

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't think it is a **exact** duplicate, as this questions wants to split all extensions, e.g. `.log.gz` from the name, not just the last one.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the file's name and extension:

```
import os
# path = C:/Users/Me/some_file.tar.gz
temp = os.path.splitext(path)
var = (os.path.basename(temp[0]), temp[1])
print (var)
# (some_file.tar, .gz)
```

Its worth noting that files with "dual" extensions will need to be recursed if you want. For example, the `.tar.gz` is a gzip file that happens to be an archive file as well. But the current state of it is `.gz`.

There is more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

General strategy: find the first '.' everything before it is the path, everything after it is the extension.

```
def get_path_and_extension(filename):
    index = filename.find('.')
    return filename[:index], filename[index + 1:]
```

Comment: And if there's a '.' in part of the path name?