# How to export text to a new file, userinput?

Tags: python, csv, input, user-input, overwrite

So i wrote a little program in python which allows me to take a .csv file, filter out the lines i need and then export these into a new .txt file.
This worked quite well, so i decided to make it more user friendly by allowing the user to select the file that should be converted by himself through the console (command line).

My problem: The file is imported as a .csv file but not exported as a .txt file which leads to my program overwriting the original file which will be emptied because of a step in my program which allows me to delete the first two lines of the output text.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks :)

```
import csv
import sys

userinput = raw_input('List:')
saveFile = open(userinput, 'w')

with open(userinput, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    count = 0

    for row in reader:
        print(row[2])
        saveFile.write(row[2] + ' ""\n')
saveFile.close()

saveFile = open(userinput, 'r')
data_list = saveFile.readlines()
saveFile.close()

del data_list[1:2]

saveFile = open(userinput, 'w')
saveFile.writelines(data_list)
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: welcome to SO, could you write to a new file instead of the old file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
userinput = raw_input('List:')
f_extns = userinput.split(".")
saveFile = open(f_extns[0]+'.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably just want to save the file with a new name, this [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python) talks about splitting out the extension so then you can just add your own extension

you would end up with something like

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(userinput)
saveFile = open(name + '.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change the extension of the output file. Here is a solution that sets the output file extension to `.txt`; if the input file is also `.txt` then there will be a problem, but for all other extensions of the input file this should work.

```
import csv
import os

file_name = input('Name of file:')

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python
file_name, file_ext_r = os.path.splitext(file_name)
file_ext_w = '.txt'
file_name_r = ''.format(file_name, file_ext_r)
file_name_w = ''.format(file_name, file_ext_w)
print('File to read:', file_name_r)
print('File to write:', file_name_w)

with open(file_name_r, 'r') as fr, open(file_name_w, 'w') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        print(row[2])

        if i >= 2:
            fw.write(row[2] + ' ""\n')
```

I also simplified your logic to avoid writting the first 2 lines to the output file; no need to read and write the output file again.

Does this work for you?