# Pythonic way to separate basename and directory-path

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple Pythonic way to parse Linux style path, while keeping the basename and the directory path in respective variables.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Comment: I updated the question. I meant to specify that I was looking for a way to separate the dir-path from the basename into two separate variables, while not affecting the input string or knowing the basename prior.

Answer (score 1):

The modern pythonic way is to use [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which provides an object-oriented interface for path manipulation:

```
from pathlib import Path

thing = Path('my/path').name
```

The oldschool (and still just fine) way to do it is to use `os.path`.

```
import os.path

thing = os.path.basename('my/path')
```

Answer (score -3):

One issue with this solution, is that it assumes that there are no repeats of the *basename* in the full path. Now, typically that is true, this solution is technically not true.

```
import os

x = "/home/first/second/third/main.cpp"
basename = os.path.basename(x)
dir_path = x.split(basename)[0]
```

A better solution would be:

```
import os

x = "/home/first/second/third/main.cpp"
basename = os.path.basename(x)
dir_path = "/".join(x.split("/")[:-1])
```

Comment: This solution appears to violate the PEP8 section on [Blank Lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). I would assume any Pythonic solutions would adhere to PEP8.

Comment: Also, this would be a better answer if you explained how to code answers the question.